# Is there a way to know which tags I created?

Tags: support, tags, taxonomist-badge, tracking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I find out which tags I have created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created)

Seeing [this question about the Taxonomist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182/is-the-taxonomist-badge-really-needed) caused me to wonder how close I am to said badge. Is there a way to see which tags I've created?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is I would love to know about it, but as far as I know there is no simple method of finding out who was the first to create a tag. In theoretical terms, you could look for the oldest item with a certain tag, but that is not a guarantee to be the originator because tags can be changed and taken away, so the oldest may have been retagged at some point.

Comment: This is no longer accurate. The dupe contains [the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108247/131713), though.