# What counts as "creating" a tag, for Taxonomist?  And what prevents gaming the badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, abuse, taxonomist-badge, gaming-the-system

The description for the Taxonomist badge is: "Created a tag used by 50 questions."  This leads me to a few questions.

Consider the following scenario:

1. Alice creates a question that is tagged with [aardvark](/questions/tagged/aardvark).  This is the first-ever question in the system tagged [aardvark](/questions/tagged/aardvark).
2. After a few days, Alice (or someone else) decides this tag isn't relevant, so it is removed.
3. After a while, Bob creates a question that is tagged [aardvark](/questions/tagged/aardvark).
4. This time, the tag sticks, and eventually forty-nine more questions are tagged [aardvark](/questions/tagged/aardvark).

This raises the questions:

- Which user gets the Taxonomist badge, Alice or Bob?

  - Alice was the first person to ever use the [aardvark](/questions/tagged/aardvark) tag.
  - When Bob used the tag, he seemed to be "creating" the tag (since it didn't exist beforehand).
- If Bob gets the credit, what if he was the one who removed the tag from Alice's post in step 2?  In that case, he would be effectively stealing the badge from Alice.

---

Some other questions about gaming the system to get this badge:

- Do the tags have to stick for a certain amount of time before the badge is awarded?
- Do the questions have to be tagged by a certain number of users?
- Could I simply go in at an off-peak hour and retag fifty questions to get the badge, then undo my changes before anyone gets mad?

  - Is anyone willing to admit that they tried this?
  - If so, were you able to get the badge this way?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question

Comment: You can't undo the evidence. Your abuse will be pretty obvious on the front page. I don't think it would be popular...

Comment: like it or not, the modern usage of "begging the question" is here to stay.  just like the modern meaning of "decimate".

Comment: Sorry.. what is the modern usage of 'decimate'? I just looked it up to make sure, and it meant exactly what I thought it meant?

Comment: modern usage: "to destroy a great number or proportion of".  older meaning: "to decrease by one tenth".

Comment: bullet abuse is a crime!

Comment: @Jeff is that a joke or is there really something wrong with the way i used bullets there?  when i had all the questions in a single paragraph it got kind of jumbled, i thought a list better organized my thoughts

Comment: I suggest whoever wants to win the bounty provide **actual examples** of people who have gotten Taxonomist through gaming.

Comment: @Jeff I was hoping someone would be willing fess up, actually... I've done more tedious things than that to get video game achievements, after all... :)  if no one does admit it (and maybe no one really has tried it?), it looks like Pesto gets some meta-rep by default. :-/

Comment: I'm currently hunting, but there's a decent chance of error since I can only view who made the latest revision, who had the original post, and the tags used. Anything which happens in between is impossible to determine ):

Comment: @Jeff: it'd be nice if you could answer my questions about what is considered a "new" tag and whether Alice or Bob would get the badge in the scenario I described.  That has nothing to do with whether or not anyone is gaming the system.

Comment: Im going on the assumption that tags are never really destroyed, so a tag is created the first time it is used and stays that way. I'm willing to temporarily retag 50 questions in mso to try, but I don't know if people would like that.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty Kip. I meant to add some more information to my answer but never really got around to it. Tags are created once, by the first person to ever use them. Even if that tag is deleted before it is used again, it has been created by the first user. Tags have to be active for a certain amount of time to stick (from what I can tell only 20-75 minutes, but some time nonetheless). Tags don't have to be used by a minimum amount of users (unless its a very small amount, but can't be inferred if it is). I believe this should answer all your questions.

Comment: @ian thanks.  i guess that means you have no way of knowing if you are creating a new tag or not, unless you data-mine old revisions in the public data dump.

Comment: It seems you can tell if a tag has been previously created by using the autocomplete. For instance I removed this tag, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=sqlserveragentjob&sort=stats&pagesize=50 , which only ever appeared once. It now shows as zero instances, however if you go to ask a question and use the autocomplete it will show it as being used once. Thus, all previously created tags will autocomplete, regardless of if they still exist.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just find some useful retagging to do than to go to all the effort of figuring out how to game the system without being thwarted, anyway? Like, find some reasonably common but ambiguous (as used) tag and split it into two or more new tags. (You might even be able to get help with the retagging itself on meta!)

Comment: This feature request is related to one of the concerns raised here (gaming the badge): [Change Taxonomist's definition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15010).

Comment: I have read a lot of topics about the badge Taxonomist, but I did not get the answer for my question: if I create new tag by editing from not my own question then who is the creator from this tag? Should I have my own question for this new tag to be a creator or not? @MarcGravell

Comment: To my previous comment above: I have found the answer **[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65556/392391)** – in this case I will get the badge Taxonomist.

Comment: I'm *so tempted* to tag this [tag:aardvark].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've wanted to find out who created which tags for awhile now to help aid me in other useful statistics, so I created an algorithm to determine who created which tag.

I've only run it on about 100 tags so far because the Taxonomist badge was released late in the game and later tags require a somewhat different method. It seems to be reasonably accurate but cannot account for deleted posts or chain editing.

So far it doesn't appear as if anyone is gaming the system, but most of the tags so far are very common (c#, java, c, etc). I'll see how things stand when I get to some of the newer tags.

A somewhat prettier version can be found [here](http://statoverflow.com/tax.php). The user for asp.net has created quite a few posts, but in defense it is a very popular tag. I know of a few tags that have been started in deleted posts, but I can't find the original owner. Python was created in such a manner.

```
Tag: c#| User: 8| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: web-services| User: 2| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: linq| User: 2| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 1
Tag: .net3.5| User: 2| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: database| User: 2| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: mysql| User: 2| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: sqlserver| User: 32| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: query| User: 2| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: language-agnostic| User: 13| Edits/Posts Before By User: 3| Edits/Posts After By User: 2
Tag: performance| User: 13| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: algorithm| User: 13| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: unix| User: 13| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: pi| User: 13| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 7
Tag: fun| User: 92| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: linux| User: 61| Edits/Posts Before By User: 3| Edits/Posts After By User: 3
Tag: vb.net| User: 33| Edits/Posts Before By User: 5| Edits/Posts After By User: 4
Tag: .net| User: 2| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 1
Tag: sql| User: 2| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: books| User: 52| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: memory| User: 39| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: web| User: 2| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: winforms| User: 231| Edits/Posts Before By User: 4| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: php| User: 48| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: com| User: 39| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: unit-testing| User: 157| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: asp.net| User: 83| Edits/Posts Before By User: 17| Edits/Posts After By User: 34
Tag: html| User: 9| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: ruby| User: 25| Edits/Posts Before By User: 11| Edits/Posts After By User: 4
Tag: web-development| User: 117| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: css| User: 9| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: text| User: 34| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: svn| User: 58| Edits/Posts Before By User: 5| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: version-control| User: 83| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: subjective| User: 92| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: development| User: 117| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: tools| User: 154| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: beginner| User: 8| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: security| User: 59| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: rsi| User: 9| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: best-practices| User: 105| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 1
Tag: mac| User: 147| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: python| User: 111| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: eclipse| User: 58| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: java| User: 78| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 1
Tag: oop| User: 58| Edits/Posts Before By User: 4| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: design| User: 63| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 2
Tag: xml| User: 78| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: c++| User: 23| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 1
Tag: c| User: 8| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: stack| User: 322| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: windows| User: 72| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: javascript| User: 238| Edits/Posts Before By User: 3| Edits/Posts After By User: 2
Tag: regex| User: 230| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: email| User: 49| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: flash| User: 231| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: files| User: 50| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: http| User: 136| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 1
Tag: vb| User: 33| Edits/Posts Before By User: 5| Edits/Posts After By User: 4
Tag: asp.net-mvc| User: 364| Edits/Posts Before By User: 9| Edits/Posts After By User: 9
Tag: ajax| User: 331| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: linqtosql| User: 51| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 4
Tag: visualstudio| User: 91| Edits/Posts Before By User: 3| Edits/Posts After By User: 7
Tag: deployment| User: 91| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 3
Tag: iis| User: 192| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: hardware| User: 556| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: sharepoint| User: 404| Edits/Posts Before By User: 3| Edits/Posts After By User: 22
Tag: ide| User: 123| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 2
Tag: wpf| User: 93| Edits/Posts Before By User: 9| Edits/Posts After By User: 3
Tag: oracle| User: 116| Edits/Posts Before By User: 8| Edits/Posts After By User: 20
Tag: browser| User: 9| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: threading| User: 257| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: search| User: 134| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: language| User: 13| Edits/Posts Before By User: 3| Edits/Posts After By User: 3
Tag: software| User: 290| Edits/Posts Before By User: 9| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: open-source| User: 199| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: shell| User: 117| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: rails| User: 136| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 3
Tag: osx| User: 137| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 1
Tag: gui| User: 123| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: api| User: 172| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: applications| User: 145| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: string| User: 115| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 1
Tag: testing| User: 157| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: orm| User: 13| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 2
Tag: exceptions| User: 233| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 1
Tag: learning| User: 573| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: e| User: 8| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: google| User: 308| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: mvc| User: 364| Edits/Posts Before By User: 9| Edits/Posts After By User: 9
Tag: forms| User: 103| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: jquery| User: 648| Edits/Posts Before By User: 3| Edits/Posts After By User: 6
Tag: programming| User: 4| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: flex| User: 0| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1297| Edits/Posts After By User: 60
Tag: coding| User: 15| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: ui| User: 117| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 1
Tag: visualstudio2008| User: 417| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 1
Tag: io| User: 9| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: gem| User: 91| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: patterns| User: 358| Edits/Posts Before By User: 2| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: r| User: 8| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 0
Tag: post| User: 15| Edits/Posts Before By User: 1| Edits/Posts After By User: 2
```

Some possible edge cases exist in the algorithm which I'll fix shortly, this is more a proof of concept.

---

**Edit:** Further info copied from a comment above:

Tags are created once, by the first person to ever use them. Even if that tag is deleted before it is used again, it has been created by the first user. Tags have to be active for a certain amount of time to stick (from what I can tell only 20-75 minutes, but some time nonetheless). Tags don't have to be used by a minimum amount of users (unless its a very small amount, but can't be inferred if it is).

Comment: If it helps you out, I know I can claim the 'string-manipulation' tag.

Comment: if someone added a nonsense tag to fifty posts, collected the badge, then rolled back those fifty edits, it wouldn't show up here would it?

Comment: Sadly no, but I think the people to abuse this are more likely to "work in" their own tags and leave them that way.

Comment: There's also  a delay in the time it takes the badge to appear, usually 80 minute intervals, but sometimes less/more. So edits have to remain in tack long enough to claim the badge.

Comment: @Ian- that's not true of all badges.  there have been times when I've gotten the "new badge" notification immediately, more often than I think could be coincidence.  particularly the ones like "first edit" "first upvote" etc.  i'd suspect that taxonomist is one that they check for on intervals rather than all the time, though, just because it seems like it'd be an expensive query.

Comment: Yeah I only meant that it was the case for this badge, I should have been more specific. It's hard to believe it could be a coincidence in this case, since they're always given in number intervals divisible by 5, at least on all the ones I've checked -- 20, 75, 80 mins are common.

Comment: Having gotten the badge in question, I see nothing here or on stat overflow that shows my userid having created a tag. Which is sad.

Comment: These are only the first 46 of the 880 badges, I never posted the complete results.

Comment: I didn't really get the answer I wanted, so I'm giving you the bounty for "most effort".  I wanted to get on here before midnight UTC and give you the bounty at the end of the day, but.. well I just forgot.  So (if I understand correctly) this is all the rep you'll get today.. sorry :-/

Comment: Congratulations.

Answer (score 28):

In my opinion Taxonomist is the badge the most people have talked about gaming the system to get.  And really, that's probably about the only way most of us could hope to achieve it any more.  I'd just as soon see it disappear completely.

Comment: Agreed         .

Comment: Good riddance, along with the Beta badge

Comment: I got it, can't remember what for. But Given the rate at which new technologies come out it should be easy enough. To get it. Just more rare...  I don't have the beta badge, And I doubt I'll get the woot badge, because I like my weekends.

Comment: Why not just retire it? There's no reason to strip those who have it. Just let it get decommissioned and live out its life floating in the StackOverflow badge harbor.

Comment: I like the beta badge. I also like letting other users (noobs) know it's there. If someone buys a stack-exchange and it's a topic I like, I'll get the beta badge on it, it's the easiest silver badge to get.

Comment: Wow that's bitterness. Just keep typing. One day you'll produce the complete works of Shakespeare. (Complete Works) badge ftw.

Answer (score 14):

I retagged 59 questions originally tagged 'gps' with a new tag, '[telematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telematics)' and got awarded the badge the next day after the retagging. A topic was opened here on MetaSO concerning the issue, and for this abuse, my account was temporarily suspended for five days and the new tag got removed, as it was considered irrelevant and synonymous with 'gps'.

Comment: thanks!  this is the kind of thing i wanted to know, and i would give you the bounty if i could. :-/

Comment: The topic opened is at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25154/tag-telematics-is-a-new-tag-but-is-currently-synonymous-with-gps

Comment: @luvieere, Odd that people who have tendencies to game systems think that everyone else is like them. This taxonomist issue is basically non-existent in many other SE sites. What I see your "crime" is is that you've simply added "telematics" as the synonym to "gps" which is a Good Thing since future users who try to tag a question as "telematics" would do so (and that question would automatically be merged into "gps") instead of leaving it untagged. Most people don't..............

Comment: ..........spend more than 20 seconds thinking of "what's the best tag I should use for this post". You should get a Martyr badge for being suspended for doing things that helps other people.

Comment: lmfao <!-irrelevant>

Answer (score 7):

Some 'game' could be played with Woot! (visit every day for 30 days) and Fanatic (visit every day for 100 days), Civic duty (vote 300 times) and Disciplined (delete your +3 voted post), Citizen Patrol (first flag), Shrunk and White (edit 100 entries). You just mindlessly do the required operations and you get them.
<strike>Its easy to avoid the retag game. Retagging should not count to this badge.</strike>

**Edit:**

I see one possibility for taxonomist: create 50 questions about a good but neglected topic on SO. My brainchild: **fork-join** in java/concurrency subtopic (its neighbor, CCR is already taken).

I'm not sure if you do them in a community wiki format, you'd still get the badge? Would be a useful game - for the learning community and for the tag creator.

**Edit2:**

Or better yet, find 50 existing concurrency question about a problem very close to fork-join and retag them.

Comment: You could actually just write a script that logs you into SO every day for 100 days... easier to game.

Comment: Or you could just visit every day for 100 days. Truly not a difficult task.

Comment: well... some of us go out of town on the weekends sometimes, and sometimes we don't have internet access in those places...

Comment: I though US is well covered with wifi/mobile/satellite net.

Comment: Depends where you go.  If you're in a reasonably-sized town (30,000 or so) and/or near an interstate, you probably have good coverage.  However, there are areas - not to far from those with good coverage - where coverage is spotty at best.

Comment: And then there are those of us in Canada, who can only get reliable internet in well-populated areas, and suffer problems with our mobile tech half a kilometre into any rural or wild area.

Comment: Did you know there are people without laptops? (For instance, I haven't got one. And my phone is so lame, it doesn't even seem to run all of the onboard games at full speed!)

Answer (score 6):

Since tags are meta data, would it really be out of bounds for me to tag (add meta data) 50 questions with taxonomist-tag-for-me to 50 questions listed on this meta site?

I could do it and see how long it takes for someone to notice :)

Comment: Funny! It's also sad to think that could actually happen.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed that this is the most likely and possible badge to "game". If I had to guess, I would expect you would at least initially be awarded the badge by going through and retagging 50 questions to a new tag and then undoing it. I wouldn't expect their to be real-time logic looking for this type of behavior. However, I would be surprised if someone were able to "game" the system in this way for long. I expect quickly someone would see you received the taxonomist badge and try to figure out how you did it. Honestly, I think of all the badges that exist, its the one I would be most likely to remove if I have the chance. In general I believe the badges do a good job of encouraging desired behavior. However, in this case, I'm not sure what type of desired behavior this would be encouraging?

To answer the first part of question. Someone who can view the code would have to give a definitive answer, but I would hope and expect that Bob would receive the badge.

Comment: Actually the easiest badge to "Game" is the Autobiographer.

Comment: True enough . . .

Comment: @Omar: I don't think that counts as gaming ;-P. (Unless you fill in garbage for no good reason, I guess...)

Comment: Analytical is even easier.

Answer (score 3):

**I hope Jeff doesn't ban me for this.**

Ok, I'll fess up! I created the Ubuntu-9.04 tag on Serverfault. I haven't got the badge yet but I check on it once in a while. I also tag any questions that are related to Ubuntu with the Ubuntu-9.04 instead of just the regular Ubuntu tag. However, I haven't went so far as to retag other people's question (that actually does cross the line IMO).

Does that make me a bad person? Am I a cheater? Maybe.

But you know what they say, If your not cheating your not trying. They also say cheaters never win.

If you do ban me I'll still read your blog.

Comment: I don't see a problem if you've tagged things that are actually ubuntu -9.04, but if the version was never specified you should remove your tags. Tags aid greatly in searching, and users searching for problems with 9.04 may find some completely irrelevant solutions.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Also has anyone notice the built in searching isn't that great/accurate.

Answer (score 3):

I see a lot of people worried about gaming badges, ESPECIALLY the taxonomist badge. But I thought about it, and it is certainly NOT the easiest badge to game.

Just looking at silver badges alone, the [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty), and [Strunk and White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) should be the easiest. Just start voting randomly on a bunch of questions and answers... or click edit on every new question you see and add something like capitalizing sentences, or just whitespace.

The [yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/13/yearling) badge would be the easiest silver badge to get, but I don't think that can be gamed.

So the question should be, how could you make a tagging incentive badge that couldn't be gamed?

Comment: The reason I don't have Stunk & White on SO yet is because the minimum reputation to edit regular (non-community) posts is still some 400 points more than I have. And generally, other people beat me to correcting the community wiki posts there. So it's not exactly the easiest to game, at least not until you have a very good rep score.

Comment: Must you edit community wiki posts? I thought any 100 questions or answers that aren't yours would do.

Comment: Until you reach 750 points you can only edit your own posts. Between there and 2000, you can edit community wiki posts, but not owned posts.

Comment: I don't count reputation as a factor in the difficulty of gaming a badge, but I see your point that there will be fewer users able to do it.

Comment: Well duh, it's not a factor if you've got the reputation. :)  Reminds me of the old adage: "why is it that some people think money isn't important? That's because they have some."

Comment: Gaming the yearling badge should not be too bad in accord with editing, especially if someone can get the +100 association bonus before they start on a new site. (Not sure when it started--Googling indicates '10-'11 or so). That's one edit per week to get to the 200 needed in a year, and so you get it before Strunk&White. I'd guess SO didn't have editing reviews for low rep users back in the early days either so it's easier now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it would be considered gaming this badge, but synonyms seem to be a good way to work towards this badge. For example take a look at user [Kris](https://serverfault.com/users/2067/kris) on Server Fault. He only has one reputation, asked only one question tagged with both "mac" and "macosx." These two terms seem to be used synonymously, at least in the context of his question.

Comment: Perhaps it would be gaming if the user was actively creating various synonyms, however this this case they've only ever posted twice. I don't think claiming tags was what they were after.

Comment: alright so its obvious now that this wasn't a case of gaming but this can still be seen as an example as how easily this badge could be obtained

Comment: Yes but it is expected when the sites are still in their infancy. *Someone* has to create the tags. It only becomes a problem when people start creating completely unnecessary tags when perfectly good ones are already available, or start editing less common tags into posts.