# What tag did I win a taxonomist badge for?

Tags: support, tags, badges, taxonomist-badge

> **Duplicate/Related:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)  
>   [Taxonomist badge: what counts as “creating” a tag? And what prevents gaming the badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/taxonomist-badge-what-counts-as-creating-a-tag-and-what-prevents-gaming-the)

How can I find out what the tag was for which I won a Taxonomist badge; this took me by surprise.

Comment: This information isn't available in the badge granting system, and Jeff has declined to implement it in the future: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge

Comment: Oddly I read that 2931 question first; you might conclude that the answer to this question was totally not clear to me from there. But my search did not find question 88 because it is NOT about the taxonomist badge.

Neither answer the basic question, can I see which tags I created? I know I can see highly voted on answers and questions, but I can't tell if I created even a single tag. I don't recall doing so AND the 373 tags I've used all seem to be used before my first use.