# Who created which tag?

Tags: support, tags, badges, taxonomist-badge

Is there a page where we can see the what tags were created by the taxonomists?

Comment: You asked from a more general point of view, but very close to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created (and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6750/what-tag-did-i-win-a-taxonomist-badge-for-closed etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is now possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge).

Simply visit the [Taxonomist badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist) on the sites and you'll see the list of Taxonomists as well as what tags they were marked as creating.

Comment: This won't always work as the tag could have been added to an older question. A rare occurrence, I'll admit, but something you need to consider.

Comment: @ChrisF: That's why I said things like "There's a chance" and "far from sure". There's no way to be sure.

Comment: Sorry - I read the first part and skimmed the rest so I missed that bit.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC you can not currently see who created what tag.