# Inform users for what tag they received the Taxonomist badge

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, taxonomist-badge

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)
>   [Can I find out which tags I have created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created)
>   [Is it at all possible to find out which tag earned me the Taxonomist badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26370/is-it-at-all-possible-to-find-out-which-tag-earned-me-the-taxonomist-badge)

When I receive a taxonomist badge, I see that it is for "Created a tag used by 50 questions" but it doesn't tell me **which** tag that was. All badges are missing this information. When you click them you get the information "which users recently received this badge" which really isn't interesting or useful.

**It would be more instructive for the users and would reinforce the desired behavior for the site if clicking on badges revealed which particular behavior contributed to achieving that badge.**

Comment: So ... many ... duplicates.....

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26370/is-it-at-all-possible-to-find-out-which-tag-earned-me-the-taxonomist-badge and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6750/what-tag-did-i-win-a-taxonomist-badge-for-closed

Comment: Really? Is that all of them? Could have sworn there were at least 4 more.

Comment: shouldn't there be something on meta like we had on user voice where duplicates are aggregated so we can see how important it is becoming etc.? I think "duplicate management" is something that the SO sites need, something to string them together over time at a technical level (each having the same "duplicate id") instead of the current loose way of relating them by closing all but one and linking them all by URLs in the comments. I would post this as a separate question but I'm sure it would be closed as a duplicate. :-0

Comment: @Edward Tanguay: Can you phrase that in the form of a `feature-request`?

Answer (score 0):

The Reason why this feature is not implemented is because it is not a part of the system to begin with. The database that records all of the badges do not actually contain any information about how the badge was acquired.

If it were to be implemented, any tag in the past would not have any information tied with it. Also, while it seems logical, I think it is fairly easy to tell what earned you a badge in almost every badge except the ones relating to tags.

Personally, I do think that it would be an improvement, even if we can't get the data for past badges, but I think there are better ways to spend the developers time.

Put short, it wasn't part of the original design, and probably won't be part of the future design.

You can see this in Jeff's answer here: [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)