# Know the number of tags created with number of use its usage

Tags: feature-request

How do I know how many tags I have created, and how many times a tag is used?

I am interested in this just to know when I am close to get "Taxonomist" badge.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6750/what-tag-did-i-win-a-taxonomist-badge-for will help you when you are awarded the badge. For your new tags, I guess you could count http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[your-tag-here] until you hit 50

Comment: @Jose K the above link is showing only "Feature" questio i.e. only bounty enabled question....

Comment: Nope, you must have set your default tab to "Featured"

Comment: @Jose ya i got it whats the problem, and i have also gone through the 1st comment you provided, but i want to know the number of tag, tag-list which i have created yet. i hope you get it now what i want to say !!

Answer (score 1):

You can see number of questions tagged at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/your-tag-name

But you can see tags created by you after getting the **Taxonomist** badge.

To see a list of all those with the badge and what tag you created (so long as it is still in use), check out the [Taxonomist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist) badge page.

To see what you alone created, check out the bottom portion of your user profile.

Comment: lolz.....[Check my SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/379693/paresh-mayani), thanx for the [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)...:D :P