# Who is the "creator" of a tag for Taxonomist purposes?

Tags: discussion, taxonomist-badge, tag-creation

When I started on Super User, I asked one question. My reputation was too small to create tags (this was before accounts being linked, so I had rep of 1), so I tagged my question with available tags. One of those tags was `[sound]` ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sound)). Now, as I see correctly, I was the first to use `[sound]`. So, am I the creator of this tag? Or — more generally — who is the creator of a tag for the purposes of the Taxonomist badge? The person who used it first to tag a question, or someone else?

I have read
[What counts as "creating" a tag, for Taxonomist?  And what prevents gaming the badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/taxonomist), but it does not state clearly who the creator will be; the discussion there is more about gaming the badge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a tag gets created by a user, it will recognize them as the creator. It is also likely that there are times when someone creates a time and then the tag "disappears" due to a merge or removal or for whatever reason. If it gets created again, I believe the original person will still be credited with the creation.

Comment: "If a tag gets created by a user, it will recognize them as the creator" is kind of circular.

Answer (score 4):

If the tag already existed then someone else with enough rep must have created it when they posted their question. They will be recognised as the creator of the tag when the time comes to award the taxonomist badge.