# If I retag someone's question, and create a new tag, is that tag still attributed to me?

Tags: discussion, badges, tags, taxonomist-badge, tag-creation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Taxonomist -– who is the “creator” of a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/taxonomist--who-is-the-creator-of-a-tag)

I recently re-tagged a question, and created a new tag in the process. If that tag becomes popular, who will get the Taxonomist badge?

Comment: You will get the badge as you created the tag.

Comment: @Chris, hm, you're right, this _is_ a dupe. Not sure why it looked different to me at first. Voting to close.

Comment: Also a related question: [Taxonomist badge: what counts as “creating” a tag? And what prevents gaming the badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/taxonomist-badge-what-counts-as-creating-a-tag-and-what-prevents-gaming-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you would get the badge. The tag wouldn't have existed until you created it, and the OP had no involvement.

Related questions:

- [Taxonomist – who is a “creator” of the tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/taxonomist-who-is-a-creator-of-the-tag)
- [Taxonomist badge: what counts as “creating” a tag? And what prevents gaming the badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/taxonomist-badge-what-counts-as-creating-a-tag-and-what-prevents-gaming-the)

Comment: @fredley, I can't delete this answer unless you un-accept it.