# Who will be considered as the creator of a tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-creation, taxonomist-badge

1. A user, Tom, asks a new question with a new tag, then promptly deletes the question after finding the post useless.

   - Since tags will automatically be deleted in a day if there are no questions tagged, the tag was automatically deleted by the system.
2. After sometime, another user, Bob, asked a new question with this tag.

#### Who will be the "creator" of a tag? Also, who will be awarded the Taxonomist Badge?

---

#### Logically, there are reasons for both of them to be the "creator":

- **Tom:** He is the first user to ever use the tag, so he is the creator.
- **Bob:** It would be fair to award the badge to him since he, sort of, made the tag popular. He also wouldn't know that Tom actually used the tag before, thinking that it's a new tag when he created it.

---

This post is similar to [Who is the "creator" of a tag for Taxonomist purposes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/who-is-the-creator-of-a-tag-for-taxonomist-purposes) and [What counts as "creating" a tag, for Taxonomist?  And what prevents gaming the badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/what-counts-as-creating-a-tag-for-taxonomist-and-what-prevents-gaming-the-b), however they are asked around 7 years ago and things may have changed now.

Comment: Have you reason to believe the logic has changed?

Comment: This would be a better question if you quoted what those old questions appeared to say on the matter. But when I read them, I decided they were not exactly crystal clear on the matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After poking around a number of related and linked questions, I found this:

> Tags are created once, by the first person to ever use them. Even if that tag is deleted before it is used again, it has been created by the first user.

-- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4934/147247

The question for that answer is concerned with gaming and other things, and this answer is not from a diamond mod, but it does appear to be definitive.

So in your example Tom would get the badge, since it was Tom who first created that tag even though it didn't get used much the first time around.

Comment: I have read a lot of topics about the badge Taxonomist, but I did not get the answer for my question: if I create new tag by editing from not my own question then who is the creator from this tag? Should I have my own question for this new tag to be a creator or not?

Comment: To my previous comment above: I have found the answer **[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65556/392391)** – in this case I will get the badge Taxonomist.