# What badge do I get by creating a new tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, badges

What badge do I get by creating a new tag? Is it [Taxonomist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist)?

Also is there any way to market a tag once created? I believe there is a legit tag missing and I want to create it.

Comment: @Java It's 250 on other sites, but SO has an higher rep requirement due to having a larger userbase.

Comment: not that I care but why would some one down vote this simple one

Comment: I think it's the reference to marketing "your" tag - though who knows.

Comment: get a life people and **keep down voting** I have got bill board for my tag erected already....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't earn a badge for simply creating a new tag. Taxonomist is close, but it does have some restrictions. From the [list of badge descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) (emphasis mine):

> #### Taxonomist
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - **Create a tag that is applied to 50 questions**
>
>   - If User A creates a tag that falls into disuse and User B later
>       uses the tag again, User A continues to get credit for creating the
>       tag, for the purposes of this badge
> - Source: [Taxonomist — who is the "creator" of a
>     tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/taxonomist--who-is-the-creator-of-a-tag)

Note, however, that [you first need 1500 rep to create a new tag on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question.

The only way to "market a tag"  is to ask great questions that need the tag. Great questions gets lots of attention and so does your tag.

If you think that there is a tag missing, and you don't have enough reputation points to create one yourself you have two possibilities:

1. Earn enough reputation to create the tag yourself.
2. Request for the tag to be created by another user, by adding a comment. You don't get the credit (Taxonomist badge) but at least the tag is free to be used.

It just depends on your priority. Credit, or tag availability.