# Do tags still exist if the only question with the tag has the tag removed?

Tags: support, tags, edits

There was one time I saw a tag that was used for only one question, but just after the question was created the tag got edited out. I think (not totally sure) that it had a tag wiki. When I clicked on the tag shown in the revision history, though, I could not find the tag wiki, which makes me wonder if the tag actually still existed.

My question is, does a tag still exist when it is are edited out of the only question that uses it? Or does it not get removed until 6 months after it was created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag will stop to exist (after being removed from the last question) when a [daily script runs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71129/295232), so much faster than the six month for tags with *one* question.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16037/295232) seems to suggest *some* information about the tag is being kept, but it's doubtful. The tag wiki you mention will be [orphaned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108631/295232) and not reinstated when the tag is created again.