# Tag 'telematics' is a new tag but is currently synonymous with 'gps'?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges, gaming-the-system

The moderator tools on SO say 'telematics' is a new tag with 59 (!) questions.

I selected the tag - up popped the list of 59 questions.  The 'gps' tag showed up as related, and listed 59 questions.  Clicking on 'gps' lists the doubly tagged 'telematics' and 'gps' tagged questions - 59 of them.

So, 'telematics' seems to be an exact synonym of 'gps'.  As such, it should be removed in favour of the older 'gps' tag (and the relevant badge rescinded).

Comment: It seems like someone went after a Taxonomist badge

Comment: This user seems to have been busy: http://stackoverflow.com/users/147141/luvieere

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely abusive. Tag removed.

I guess this answers my "show me actual abuse of the Taxonomist badge" question, but this is the only one I know of. And there will be .. serious consequences.

Comment: In that case, I'm cancelling my plans to introduce the 'maple-syrup-waffle-laser-bee' tag tonight around midnight.

Comment: See, I *told* you!! ;)

Answer (score 9):

There are a few ways to combat this:

1. Require a tag to be used by **50 users** and not 50 questions.
2. Rate limit the use of re-tagging by the same user.
3. Require a week 'cool-down' period after the tag is created and used by 50 questions until the badge is awarded. It should give plenty of time for other users to spot gaming and revert.
4. Get rid of the taxinomist badge. It has invited more than its fair share of controversy.

---

Regarding the user in question, I asked him via Stack Overflow about the tagging. [He responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539012/creating-a-path-in-wpf-programatically/1539131#1539131):

> Yup...went on a tagging spree... However, I didn't do it with the intent of inducing erroneous tagging, as ideed, gps technology is a subset of telematics. Telematics, or telemetry, is a technology that allows remote measurement and reporting of information, thus including a wider variety of fields than just gps: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telemetry. I stand by my action, as further questions targeting the integrated use of telecommunications and informatics may very well choose the tag as a valid one. – luvieere 6 hours ago

Take that response how you will.

Comment: I think #1 and #3 would be sufficient.  I'd hate to see #2, since I often need to retag a *lot* and I know other editors do too.  #4 wouldn't bother me.  Let everyone who currently has the badge keep it, but declare that the land-rush is over.

Comment: I'd prefer #1 and #3 as well; but #2 and #4 are 'other' options.