# Cross site reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

Is it possible to earn cross site reputation? I [answered an old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110675/tag-badge-triggered-by-retagging-potential-for-abuse/267535#267535) awhile ago, and referenced a post on Meta Stack Overflow. I got a comment from [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) saying

> Cross site points. Enjoy!

Of course I can't get reps on a meta site, but what if I would have referenced the parent Stack Overflow site? Would I have got reps there, or was that a joke?

> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can attract an audience to a post by strategically linking to them from post or comments. Some of those visitors might decide to vote, either up or down. If done from a site-meta it is known as [the meta-effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture).

But that is not real cross-site rep.

You can get an [association bonus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302340/should-the-association-bonus-be-reversed-if-it-was-obtained-by-serial-voting) once you reach 200 reputation on any site. On all other sites in your network profile you get [100 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), unleashing a fair amount of moderation abilities and features without posting any question/answer or be active on those sites.

So, was @ShadowWizard joking? Yes and no. In general, stay away from the wizards.

Comment: 'In general, stay away from the wizards.' - wtf you don't accept magic?!

Comment: Excellent answer from my favorite magical flower! :D

Comment: "...stay away from the wizards..." "...for they are subtle, and quick to anger."