# Most MATLAB questions being tagged as Octave

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There appears to be a user who is adding the [octave](/questions/tagged/octave) tag to most new [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) questions (see the [list of recent Octave questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/octave)). This affects dozens of questions.

Is this really appropriate? I know Octave is supposed to be an open-source MATLAB replacement, but if the user doesn't explicitly ask for Octave I don't think it should be re-tagged.

MATLAB and Octave are not always identical, although they often strive to be. An answer for one does not *necessarily* work in the other. Adding an Octave tag often adds it to the post's browser title, and makes it seem like an Octave solution is acceptable.

This seems wrong to me. Should I go back and remove the tag on all these posts? There are lots.

If this practice *is* acceptable, then the tags should simply become synonyms of each other.

**Update**: The tag was not being applied to *all* new matlab posts, as originally described, but many of them which were thought to be cross-compatible with Octave. See discussion in comments below.

Comment: This is absolutely not acceptable *unless* the question is also *about* Octave.  As in, mentions it in the question body or in the comments.  Wow, it looks like this has been going on for *days*.

Comment: yup. should i start going through these or is there a way to revert all of his edits?

Comment: There are nearly 400 [tag:octave+matlab] questions.  Perhaps there's a nice convenient diamond moderator tool that can mass-revert edits?

Comment: just checked his [edit list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1609556/carandraug?tab=activity&sort=revisions). looks like he's done about a quarter of those himself (**106!**), just in the past few days

Comment: @Charles: There's certainly one to tell the user to stop doing this. :)

Comment: I've left a comment on one of the edited questions pointing him to this discussion.

Comment: Hi! Thanks @Bart for pointing this out. I would like to point out that I'm not adding the Octave tag to **all** question of Matlab, only to the ones that make sense to do so and the syntax overlaps. I have also added other tags beside Octave, and even removed tags that make no sense. I do read the question (and answer them when I can), to make sure the retag is correct.

Comment: So the question being posed is, *why* would they make sense?  Sure, MATLAB and Octave are similar, but they're not the exact same.  My gut feeling is that tagging questions with both only makes sense when the *original question references both*.

Comment: @Makoto which is what I did. Only when it was referent to both did I made the retag. You will see no Octave tag from me in other questions such as the ones involving GUI, very specific matlab stuff, questions that I knew could not be answered by someone that new Octave only. They make sense to be together when questions are how to things with the language since that;s the only thing that they share (vectorize for loops, how to get specific indexes, use filter functions, etc).

Comment: basically, only when the question is related to the matlab programming language does it make sense to retag. Not when the question is related to the whole matlab environment. That seems like a reasonable rule, which I did follow.

Comment: @carandraug: Can you share your rationale for retagging [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13654343/102937)?  Yours is the first edit, and the original question never mentioned Octave.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that question is in relation to the programming language only. It's hard to understand what the question is, others have left comments mentioning already that, but the problem is either because of confusion with complex numbers or syntax. Not matlab specific, and definetely shared with Octave.

Comment: octave is buggy. i don't think it's appropriate to assume an answer will work in both octave and matlab, *before you even know what the answer is*. besides, i'm not really sure what's gained by adding the octave tag. octave users know to search for matlab code when they can't find an answer otherwise.

Comment: also, see [*your own answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12084522/353278) re: the differences between octave and matlab. octave has extra syntax features, handles nested functions differently, etc. you simply can't be sure that every answer someone will give will work in both.

Comment: @Jeff all software is buggy, matlab inclusive, but that's beyond the point. Adding the Octave tag means that users following that tag only can also see the question. I was only following Octave for a while until I noticed that I could also answer the problems tagged with Matlab. Not everyone here is making questions (I never asked a question in SO, I only like to solve problems). As I also wrote on that answer, it's up to the person writing the code to make it also run in Matlab (which I try to always do in those cases).

Comment: ok, let me clarify: the cross-compatibility of octave and matlab is buggy. if matlab or octave is buggy on its own, that's irrelevant. what's important is that by adding an octave tag, you are soliciting answers that might not work for the OP, and for very little payoff. like you said, it's up to the person writing the code to make sure it runs in matlab--but surely you can't expect SO users to make sure all of their octave answers work in matlab as well?

Comment: the buggyness is on functions that have not been implemented yet in which cases, I did nothing. Questions #13650730, #13649359 and #13642390 (asking for mapping, audio and bioinformatics) are the last ones I read and did not tag because of that so the answer is compatible. But there's more. Just go to page 2-3-4 (so it's not affected by me having been suspended because of this) of matlab tagged questions. You will see that only half of them have the octave tag. All of them related to the language, none incompatible.

Comment: it doesn't let me edit the comment... I did not inconsiderately started adding the tag, they were all thought first so that there would be no incompatibility issues.

Comment: @carandraug this kind of borderline vandalism tagging behavior is grounds for timed suspension.

Comment: @carandraug Though your intentions were most likely positive and constructive, please do come to Meta first the next time. Don't take such decisions on your own, especially if this would affect a very significant number of questions. Tag deletion proposals, tag changes and anything related come up here all the time and the community will have a look at it. Once we're settle on a yes or no, we will even help out. So next time, make that your course of action. I have given an answer below explaining why I feel you should not have made the changes.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I think carandraug did this with the best intentions. It is a little strong to call "vandalism" (even if boderline), an action so difficult to evaluate in moral/ethical grounds. I have a conter exmaple to what was shown here. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778644/iterating-over-values-from-fixed-sum-in-matlab/9851627#9851627) was answered with an Octave solution, that is, it is useful to Octave users, but since there is no Octave tag, they wont find it. I think it is to an Octave user to define if a question is relevant or not, not to a matlab user.

Comment: I personally find that suspending a person that had helped so much is rather unfair. Also the post says "adding the octave tag to all new matlab questions", this is not true. Is there a personal/non-professional/conflict-of-interests reason behind all this issue?

Comment: @JuanPi Octave users will find that solution just fine since they will more than likely know to look for Matlab solutions as well. And after 106 such edits I can't be surprised that the impression was the user was going for all the questions. I don't see the remark as an indication of personal conflict or any such matter.

Comment: @JuanPi no, it was not personal. i was reading matlab questions and saw they were all edited by the same user, so i took notice. i have nothing personal against him and wasnt trying to get anyone suspended, but i did think the edits should stop

Comment: @JuanPi I don't see it as very different from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25154/tag-telematics-is-a-new-tag-but-is-currently-synonymous-with-gps/25188#25188

Comment: @JeffAtwood very slightly. First, the user did not explain their rationale about his actions. carandraug did. He also responded to all the "accusations" clearly demonstrating willingness to amend his actions or at least make public his reasons. Are the moderators sure that they want to punish this behavior? under these observations, the relation to the post you link is very superficial. Are there reasons to believe carandraug was huting badge? Most of the tagged questions he answered, satisfactorily in most cases! I guess telling him to stop and ask meta first is enough.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I really don't think that my actions can be counted as vandalism. About the question you linked: I'm not after any badges (what's bothering me is that I'm being labelled as inconsiderate and worse), and this is not a case of 1 tag incorporating all the others, it's a case of where sometimes they overlap (please, see the reply I'm giving to Bart below too).

Comment: @Bart if a user knows that he can search for Matlab to get an answers in cases such as that, then an Octave tag is already valid there. And the tags I added were only for such cases.

Comment: @Jeff could you edit your question to mention this discussion? That it was not "all", only in cases where they overlap. The question should be, what to do in such cases. Also, apologies for creating 3 comments, I did not knew I was limited to 1 person per reply.

Comment: @carandraug I have already stated my view on this in my answer below. I disagree that the Octave tag should be there if the question does not explicitly mention Octave, or is unique to Octave only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There will be cases where an Octave user attempts to do something the MATLAB way, runs into a problem, and then uses Google to find out the right workaround for Octave.

By tagging most of the MATLAB problems with Octave, you remove the ability to search for Octave specific problems - when they search for "Octave specific-problem-x", they will see a relevant question here tagged with Octave, but having the same non-working MATLAB solution they've seen everywhere else.

The programs are compatible, but they are not the same.

In cases where the OP does not mention both in their post or comments, the question should be tagged only with the one they mention or tagged it with.

Octave users know full well to search for MATLAB answers when they have a question - it's not a problem for them.

When they search for Octave answers though, we should NOT be returning MATLAB results that weren't Octave to begin with.

Therefore, please do not tag MATLAB questions with Octave by default.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25154/tag-telematics-is-a-new-tag-but-is-currently-synonymous-with-gps/25188#25188

Comment: @JeffAtwood, I wouldn't say that's very related. There is a big difference between vandalism or thoughtless badge-hunting on the one hand versus a (perhaps misguided) attempt at being constructive on the other hand.

Comment: @ben that was also an attempt at being constructive.

Answer (score 13):

I would not tag Matlab questions [octave](/questions/tagged/octave), even when it could apply to both. Sure, a lot of Octave users might be helped equally well by the content and it might be equally applicable. But it is not what the OP used.

In addition, most Octave users will know about the large overlap between Octave and Matlab. For me it is explicitly why I started using Octave when I no longer had access to Matlab. Even the Octave website states *"The Octave language is quite similar to Matlab so that most programs are easily portable."*

While you could interpret that as "see, the questions are equally well served by both tags", I would say that it rather means that the Octave tag is not necessary since most users will be aware of Matlab and its applicability to their problems.

Unless a user is explicitly stating to be using Octave (or the question really is Octave-specific), I would not add that tag.

Answer (score 12):

My gut feeling seems to go towards the side of "revert these changes".  While the two programs may be similar, there can be very specific questions involving either MATLAB or Octave.  We shouldn't do the work of the OP to determine which one they *meant* - we should have faith in the asker to add the appropriate tags.

There are cases in which adding a tag to a question is justified, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778644/iterating-over-values-from-fixed-sum-in-matlab/9851627#9851627)was answered with an Octave solution, when will the new tag be applied? If there isn't a person like carandraug reviewing all these, this will be always be tagged ad matlab and not octave.

Comment: But why would this question need the Octave tag, though?  I don't see a strong motivation since it's not a question *specific* to Octave, but more generalized with MATLAB.

Comment: Well, is there a way to tag answers? Because the solution may be very pertinent for somebody looking for octave answers, and if the question is not tagged, how this person will find the answer?

Comment: I'm of the influence that someone looking for Octave answers knows to look at MATLAB solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

This has been said in different words by other answers, but I think this has to be frowned upon or us VB.NET users could go wild adding that tag to all the C# .NET questions that are not specific to the syntax!

Comment: Rather, I think the C# tag should be *removed* in favour of the .net tag when it's not syntax-specific. =)

Comment: @J.Steen I agree with you, as long as people see the :-) variant at the end of your comment! (I.e. I _don't_ think we should be actually doing this because it has been long held that a questioner's tags are to be left unless they're actually wrong.)

Comment: Yeah, my comment certainly had a serious tone of inseriousness. =)