# Tag-badges exploit

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-badges

Like everyone else I've been reading bobince's outbreak about parsing [html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) with great amusement. When I read in the comments that bobince had been awarded two gold badges (html and regex) for this single post, something occured to me. What would happen if I edited the question and added another tag? Unable to resist the urge I appended the "parsing" tag to the OP.

It took a few hours, but sure enough. bobince is now proud owner of the gold medal "parsing" badge. That means that we currently have a mechanism that allows any owner of a 1000+ votes post to receive any tag gold badge they'd like, and even funnier is the fact that anyone else can reward them with an arbitrary gold medal.

Comment: Maybe this is how that coveted **Generalist** badge will be gained/gamed.

Comment: After posting this, Emil, bobince's answer will get locked soon :)

Comment: I'd add a plzsendtehcodez tag.

Comment: I forsee him getting gold "Ponies", "jon-skeet", and "waffles" badges.

Comment: +1 for scientific experimentation.

Comment: did i miss something?  how'd he get 1700 upvotes in nine days?  what drew so many people to the post?

Comment: @Kip: Jeff posted an link on Coding Horror. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001311.html  It was like catnip for nerds. :)

Comment: Heh. Yes, if you added the tag just to test the system please do remove it and have ♦ fix as necessary... I wouldn't mind having a gold ponies badge though.

Comment: He could have the only gold "beta" badge! Or a "Founder" badge like Jeff and Joel were going to have! Or a "bobince" badge of awesomeness! Or just an "awesome" badge! The possibilities are endless!

Comment: @bobince, I've removed the tag. Let's see if it disappears by itself during some nightly batch job or something. Otherwise, I'm sure that someone with database access who sees this can remove it if you really want to get rid of that extra gold badge. :)

Comment: @Emil H - As far as I'm aware (based on the discussion in this thread and elsewhere) the badge won't really go away. The SO badge system checks for badges being earned, but not being kept.

Comment: @CMNC, Yeah, I don't think it will disappear automatically either.

Comment: If you really want to be cruel to bobince you can add a `downvote-me` tag to the question. It's like an SO-badge version of a "kick me" sign!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is now a minimum-answer requirement for tag badges, which wasn't implemented in response to this question; this one was just resolved in a quick-and-dirty manner.

Comment: Darn. Someone should've added the [tag:deadpool] tag before this got fixed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Good point -- I converted it to wiki. Though I think everyone involved deserved the rep and badges they got thus far, without the Parsing badge..

Comment: You are NO FUN AT ALL, you know that?

Comment: Will they lose the rep in a recal?

Answer (score 77):

I'd just like to point out that I alone prophesied that this sort of thing could happen months ago in [a post on uservoice](https://web.archive.org/web/20091122155844/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/201012-potential-to-game-the-specialist-badge-system).

Alas, no one listened, and now you have only yourselves to blame! Oh, the horror! Your hubris has caused something to be **wrong** on the internets! We are all done for!!!

Comment: I wish I could +1000 this and change the tags on this question to `[time-traveler]` or something actually funny

Comment: Voted up to +3. Only 997 to go...

Comment: We should add and remove the **`[2012]`** tag to the question, since bobince obviously represents the apocalypse.

Comment: @Changing: At the very least we need to make sure his answer ends up with 2012 votes.

Comment: I agree. I've already contributed my best efforts.

Comment: Well done. Doesn't it feel good to see that you were right, though? :)

Comment: I added the "fulfilled-prophecy" tag in your honor. I envision it'll take a while before you have 1000 votes, though.

Comment: Obligatory wrong on the internets link: http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: +1 for a predicatively appropriate user name...

Answer (score 15):

I agree with Adam here (I even up-voted his answer). The number of times this would be a problem doesn't warrant the effort it would take to fix.

Under normal conditions an answer would probably be converted to CW long before it reached the 400, let alone 1000, vote mark. I've just checked and there are no other 400+ vote answers that aren't community wiki ([votes:400 wiki:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=votes%3A400+wiki%3A0))

This has also highlighted a bug. [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) hasn't got the silver 400 vote badges for [regex] and [parsing] yet. He had previously earned the [html] silver badge.

If you check the [silver regex](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/97/regex) and the [gold regex](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/133/regex) you'll see one user in each and they're different! There's not even a [silver parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) page.

Comment: Can we revisit this? This is simply no longer true. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=votes%3A1000+wiki%3A0

Comment: @Miles The badge rules have been tightened up since these answers were posted. You can no longer get a tag badge from a single answer. You need 20 for the bronze badge alone.

Answer (score 12):

In principle, this is a problem.  In practice, there are [only four posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=votes%3A1000) with 1000+ votes, and the other three (besides this one) are all CW.

I'm not sure what the best way to fix this would be that is still fair.  I have an ugly feeling this will fall into the edgecase/wontfix bin.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that there's very few 1000+ posts. Still, stackoverflow will hopefully be around for many, many years. Some answers accumulate more votes with time, so who knows how many such posts there'll be in 10 years? :) I agree that it isn't a very urgent problem. Just thought it'd be worth mentioning.

Comment: On the other hand... This will no doubt work for silver badges with 400+ votes as well. There's a lot of those.

Comment: @Emil: Good point.  I agree it's a problem, but unless you can think of a sensible and simple way to prevent it, I can virtually guarantee it will not be addressed by the dev team.  Worse problems with simpler solutions have lingered for longer.

Comment: @Emil: Actually, if you check ChrisF's response, you can see that there are, in fact, no other 400+ vote answers that aren't CW either.

Comment: Ok, fair point. :)

Comment: my "256 is a nice round number" answer is almost there! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164556). in fact, it would be over 1000 votes except for the fact that everyone tried to hold it down to exactly 256 votes for so long. :) (102 downvotes as of last data dump- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11022)

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea you could search like that. Awesome.

Answer (score 6):

To everyone suggesting that this problem doesn't really matter because there just aren't many 1000+/400+ answers, note that tag score also matters for the (arguably more important) tag synonym system.

Feel like proposing/voting on tag synonyms, but don't have the necessary tag score?  If you've got an answer with score 5, you're good to go!  Add the desired tag, wait until you're credited for it, then propose/vote to your heart's content!  With a few similarly situated friends you can even get that synonym approved immediately!

Answer (score 3):

If you suspect tag abuse, flag the question and a moderator will deal with it.  Given that there are few of them, this doesn't require a technical solution, and if the abuse gets bad then the question can be locked.

Answer (score 2):

At most, he will just gain 5 golden badges for 5 tags. Still, I wonder... If someone would remove a tag, would he lose a badge again?

I think it's quite exceptional when someone gains 1000 votes with one answer. That should be worth a badge per tag. :-) (Basically, a golden badge for at least every 200 votes.)

Comment: Badges aren't normally lost (the [beta] badge being an exception)

Comment: If the question is edited with new tags every few hours, there is no limit to the number of badges he will get.

Comment: As I understand it, if you remove a tag to make space for the new tag, the system will award the new badge, not remove the old badge, but also not update the count, because it knows he's "short" one now.  So he'll get at most 5 badges added to the count, but a potentially unlimited number shown in his profile.

Comment: I think tag badges do get removed.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to do a similar experiment .. I was going to edit 50 questions and insert an arbitrary tag to see if I'd win the 'taxonomist' badge.

It seemed a little destructive to do as an experiment, so I didn't do it .. but would still be interested in knowing if it would have worked.

Comment: @tinkertim: See this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2931  And in particular, this answer:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25357

Comment: @Kip: Thanks! Interestingly enough, it worked.