# What what? [regex] badge error?

Tags: bug, tag-badges, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag-badges exploit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30193/tag-badges-exploit)

According to [the badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags), there has been 1 silver and 1 gold badge awarded for the **`[regex]`** tag on Stack Overflow. So I said "congrats" to the guy who's gotten 1000 upvotes for regexes, then clicked to see who it was.

I clicked on the silver badge. [It's Gumbo!](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/97/regex)

Then, for some reason, I clicked on the gold badge. [It's bobince!?](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/133/regex)

How does bobince have a gold regex badge but not a silver regex badge? Isn't that kind of impossible? Shouldn't there, by definition, be two people with silver  regex badges, bobince and Gumbo?

Just to verify, litb and paxdiablo have both the C [silver](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/52/c) and [gold](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/96/c) badges, and Peter Hosey has both the [silver](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/69/cocoa) and [gold](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/113/cocoa) Cocoa badges (badges chosen because of the small number of users to verify, and also I just got the C silver badge so it was on my mind). What gives?

Comment: Noted already at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30193/tag-badges-exploit

Comment: My bad. Why am I not allowed to automatically close my own questions?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate - this particular effect (straight to gold, no silver) isn't mentioned in the other question, though they are closely related.

Comment: @Adam - It is mentioned in the answer, and I think future discussion of this bug should be in that thread too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

bobince's regex answer rose *very* quickly.  It could be that the trigger is layered so you can't get two badges for the same accomplishment - in other words, the threshold for gold was passed before the badge tests were applied, and it simply gave the higher badge, rather than both at once.

Comment: Holy balls, that's a high-rated answer. That'll teach me not to look at profiles first.

Comment: This was my gut reaction, too, when it was first brought up.

Comment: @CABAG - Dude.  I've heard tales of your epic "gut reactions."  *Please visit the restroom next time*

Comment: Ah, toilet humor. The most sophisticated kind.

Comment: @Adam: I didn't know you followed me on Twitter. Hrm, need to start self-censoring there.

Comment: Hey, it's *your* fault I'm stalking you.  *I'm* the victim here.

Answer (score 3):

Oh yes, I am the awkward test case that breaks all your lovely coding. Look on my inexplicably-overrated answers, ye mighty, and despair!

Comment: -1 your answer isn't overrated, it's one of the most beautiful things I've seen on Stack Overflow. (Just kidding about the -1 though.)

Comment: The end is nigh! Bobince the Destroyer approacheth!

Comment: @Prophet formerly known as Gnovice - I love your new username and profile. Best use of the name-changing gag yet (far better than my weak attempt at meta-Meta).