# Do Ruby on Rails questions have to have the tag [ruby]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On guidelines to tagging and avoiding unnecessary tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61307/on-guidelines-to-tagging-and-avoiding-unnecessary-tags)

I'm reading and answering questions with tag [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) on Stack Overflow. These questions can be divided into three categories:

1. Can be fully answered by a [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) programmer; not related to [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails).
2. Directly related to Ruby on Rails, but it can be answered by someone who knows only Ruby.
3. Can be answered only by a Ruby on Rails professional.

Which tags must each of these categories have? I think they should be:

1. [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)
2. both [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) and [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails)
3. [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails)

I very much want to clean up this chaos, so I need your opinion in case I'm wrong.

Comment: You can add ruby-on-rails to your "Ignore Tags".

Comment: @nhnb, a looot of people think, that Ruby == Rails — that's why often true-ruby-questions tagged only with rails. I can't ignore them. And problem is not in that I don't want to see rails' questions. I just want ruby-related questions to be tagged properly.

Comment: @Shog9, why to close this question and not this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32446/should-jquery-questions-always-be-tagged-with-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Almost every single question marked with Ruby-on-Rails (or some variant of it) is also marked with Ruby. The thing is, most of these questions are not about Ruby proper, but about Rails-specific topics such as:

- Rails MVC patterns
- Rails objects
- Rails methods
- Rails gems
- Rails views
- *et cetera ad nauseum*

While you can do exclusive searches, following the [ruby] tag doesn't make much sense since it's so abused. I'd love to see a cleanup to remove the [ruby] tag from Rails-specific questions, and do something to encourage people to avoid tagging all things Rails as Ruby questions.

Answer (score 2):

The tagging system is used to target the question to people capable of answering and make it findable for people with the same problem. I therefore tend to tag a question as accurately as possible. This includes all broad category, language, as well as fine grained information such as framework and problem category, if applicable.

My go would be to tag with both `ruby` and `ruby-on-rails`.

This allows for the question to be found searching for [ruby] as well as [ruby*] and [ruby-on-rails]. Omitting `ruby` narrows the search options.