# Ruby on Rails questions being tagged with Ruby incorrectly?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Ruby on Rails questions have to have the tag [ruby]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65238/do-ruby-on-rails-questions-have-to-have-the-tag-ruby)

I have been reading through the Ruby tagged questions, and a great deal of the Ruby on Rails questions have been also tagged with Ruby as well, even though the questions are specific to Ruby on Rails, not Ruby.

I'm new here and was wondering what the best way to handle this is?

I also don't know how to tag this question appropriately.

Comment: I'd say you did a pretty good job tagging this question. Welcome to MSO, David! (I'd answer you, but I don't know enough about Ruby.)

Comment: I've sometimes seen the opposite: questions that can be answered by any Rubyist being tagged ruby-on-rails. In their defense, Rails strongly monkeypatches Ruby, such that a newbie might not know which part is Ruby and which part is Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the correct way to bump an old question (by answering it), but I'm giving it a shot.

This question was asked in late 2010 and, still, the SAME problem persists.

Ruby tagging is a mess. Everyone indiscriminately tag "ruby" and "ruby-on-rails" on almost every Rails question. Sometimes, even the other way around.

Most of the times, people won't bother about correctly tagging version-specific or version-indifferent questions. It's very common to see even **experienced** users to tag "ruby-on-rails", "ruby-on-rails-3" and "ruby" on a simple, version-unaware Rails question.

Tagging is clear in both Rails and Ruby tag wikis, but, apparently, no one reads it.
I've tried editing a few questions, correcting tags. But to no use. They just keep coming.

How can this be solved?

If this isn't the correct way of bumping an old question, please, tell me and I will delete this answer and do it properly!

Thank you!

Comment: Using an answer just to bump is indeed generally considered wrong. (If you're actually answering the question, and the bump is a side effect, that's okay.) [This FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) is the more or less official resource on how to bump appropriately... the answers there aren't very satisfying, though.