# Should all old questions have linked questions working properly?

Tags: support, linked-questions

[Ruby on Rails questions being tagged with Ruby incorrectly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71263/ruby-on-rails-questions-being-tagged-with-ruby-incorrectly) doesn't have [Do Ruby on Rails questions have to have the tag [ruby]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65238/do-rails-questions-have-to-have-the-tag-ruby) mentioned in the Linked questions, or vice versa. This may change once this question gets asked!

Is this because old questions don't have linked questions calculated automatically, or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The system avoids adding links from automatically generated "possible duplicate" comments to the Linked questions list. Whether this is intentional or not is [up for debate](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/470/linked-question-not-showing-up-on-sidebar/471#471).

Comment: Thanks. Duplicate questions are the bane of Stack Overflow, so I hope they clarify the situation soon.