# Thoughts regarding possibly dependent tags

Tags: discussion, tags

If I wanted to ask a question about [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), should I also add the tag [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)? Similarly, if I were to ask a question about [gnome](/questions/tagged/gnome), should I also add the tag [linux](/questions/tagged/linux)? [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)? Maybe there could be something automatic done about this?

Comment: As far as automated processes, this has [been declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags) rather forcefully. Given the presence of a 5 tag limit, a tag implication system can become very messy. There's a couple other posts on varying other kinds of dependencies - I don't think there's a strict rule since there's different scenarios between versioning, subsets, and other forms. [Eins](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61307/), [zwei](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32446/).

Comment: I'm glad there's a duplicate now that includes the word "dependent"; that was all I could think of to search for

Answer (score 1):

I think we should have a "hierarchy" of tags, such that tagging something [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) also makes it show up under [python](/questions/tagged/python) without having to put "python*" in order to catch it.

But we need to be careful and proactive, since [gnome](/questions/tagged/gnome) isn't necessarily related to [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), and there are many tags which could be located in multiple places in the hierarchy (none come to mind at the moment).