# Can questions tagged with [symfony1] & [symfony2] have PHP's syntax highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

Many askers set the [symfony1](/questions/tagged/symfony1) or [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2) tag without the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag.

I usually retag them adding [php](/questions/tagged/php) or using `<!-- language: lang-php -->` for specific part but I don't think this is the best way to do.

Can questions with these tags also be automatically colorized with PHP's syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[symfony1](/questions/tagged/symfony1) seems to have the default language hint already, so code should still highlight somewhat.

That said, I've changed it to PHP and added the same hint to [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2).

Comment: Ahh! My favorite Unicorn! You made my day again, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I really agree with this! I've stumbled on few Symfony question today and had to edit them in order to make them readable.

I didn't want to retag the question to PHP since the question was really about Symfony precisely and that tagging [superset is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99074/192622).

It's kind of annoying to read code without coloration, and kind of useless to edit all the posts on a question just to get coloration!

---

It could be done at the same time to some other big PHP framework like *(be free to edit to add some)*

[cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework) [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter)