# If someone tags a jquery question with javascript and not jquery, should the javascript tag be removed when the jquery tag is added?

Tags: discussion

My title pretty much says it all. This is closely related to this question: [Should jQuery questions always be tagged with "javascript"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32446)

Comment: I would be very cautious about *removing* an OP's tag unless it really, really doesn't belong. There's not much point and it just leads to distracting conversation about whether it belonged there or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this question. jQuery is an API written in and for JavaScript, but there are also core features of the language which might not be covered by jQuery. For example, a question about displaying the current time using a particular time format may involve both jQuery and core JavaScript.

In the end, do what is least distracting. The point is to get good answers. Tag editors should really only shoot for "good enough" to get the question before the right audience and to provide the necessary information to answer the question. Personally, I wouldn't remove one of the tags selected by the OP unless it clearly does *not* belong there.

Comment: +1 and I'll accept when the system will allow me. I liked "do what is least distracting"

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, `jQuery` is written in `JavaScript`, so this isn't technically incorrect.

If the actual issue is a `jQuery` issue, by all means, *add* the tag. However, many issues in usage of `jQuery` are actually regular `JavaScript` issues - such questions should be left alone.

Answer (score 1):

*This is closely related to...* you're asking the same thing. Anyways, to answer your question, yes. If it's specifically a jquery question, and they want a jquery answer, tag it with the jquery tag. Only makes sense to me. You can leave the javascript tag though. No harm is being done.

Comment: The other question was about re-tagging old questions that were originally tagged as "jquery" as "javascript". Specically, that poster was concerned about those who would do it just for the +2

Comment: Fwiw, when that question was asked, there was no +2...