# Can you get vote count related badges from CW?

Tags: discussion, badges, community-wiki

This is the way I understand how CW works:

- All points from votes you get before your answer is made CW is kept even after you turn it into CW
- Future votes from that point on do not get you points

I'm fine with that, but I have a question regarding whether future votes after that can still get you [Good Answer] etc badges or not.

The situation is that I have what I consider an "okay" answer, and it has gotten me enough votes that I really don't care about any points that it may/may not generate in the future. I do care about improving the answer, consolidating all the bits and pieces from other people's answer into my answer (which wouldn't be ethical unless I made it CW, I think, otherwise that's just plagiarism, right?), to make it one wonderful super answer.

I'm fine with not getting any more points from this answer, but my hope is that it'll get enough upvotes (because it's super awesome now with parts from everybody's answer merged into it) to still give me these badges.

So, does turning your answer to CW also forfeits future badges in addition to future points?

---

Does it also forfeit any counting of future votes in your tag-specific stats? Because I'm fine with not getting points from it any more, but I still want the votes to count for badges and for tag-specific stats.

Answer (score 2):

You still get the Nice/Good Answer badges. <s>But I don't think</s> it does not count for the tag stats.

Oh, and you do not get [tag based badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30193/tag-badges-exploit).

For further reading look into the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work).