# Can tag badges be gamed by editing the tags of a question which has an answer which was previously upvoted?

Tags: discussion, badges, gaming-the-system

Tag badges are currently earned by receiving an upvote to an answer provided for a question having a specific tag. If someone wanted to game the system would it be possible by going back to questions they've already received an upvote in and editing the tags on those questions to include one or more tag they are seeking a badge for?

Obviously, this is not something I'm suggesting anyone attempt, but this potential exploit came to mind and I wanted to make sure it had been accounted for.

Comment: You will always feel like you're being followed. Everywhere you go, you will feel that unpleasant sensation that someone is watching you.  And then, that day at home when you least expect it, he will strike for the first of many times... Editing your posts, always watching over your shoulder and making sure all questions a properly tag. Giving you that little -1 to make sure the post badge isn't gained by cheating. Then, only then, will you regret the day you made this idea public. You brought this on yourself... The retagger..  Ṱ̨̗h͚̱e ̰̲r̪e̘̘͡t̰͙̼̰͈̫̤a̹͉̟̹̘̥ͅgg͚͇̦̣̮͠e̷̫̖r̴̖ ͏̰̜̘

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

If you are at 98 votes (say) for badge "A" and have a answer with 2 up-votes you can edit the question to include badge "A". You will then get the tag badge - assuming that you have answered enough questions etc.

However, if you do this a lot it will be spotted and if you re-tag inappropriately someone will roll back the edit. If this takes you back under the criteria you **will** lose the badge.

Far better to spend your time and effort looking for new questions to answer - you'll get the badge eventually and even some more rep in the process.

Comment: Now that these do get revoked, [the original predicted exploit is not as powerful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30193/tag-badges-exploit/30216#30216). Any valid badges earned in this fashion will stick around for being valid tagging.

Answer (score 3):

I think this has been considered, probably in chat or comments because I can't find a link. Seems to me it wouldn't matter. Unlike "regular" badges, tag badges are automatically removed when the conditions for them are no longer met. So all you'd have to do is revert the tag vandalism and the badge would go poof.

Answer (score 0):

If you see an example of tag vandalism, if you have the rep, you should fix it.

But should you also flag the event under an 'other' flag?  Will the change history allow admins to see what tag vandalism you've taken out and won't make you appear to be a time-waster?