# Is a user's tag score based on the original tags of a question, or can retagging existing questions change it?

Tags: support, tags, tag-score

Suppose someone provides an answer for a question tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python). The answer is upvoted once. I notice that the question deals with regular expressions in Python, so I add the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tag as well. Will the user have his/her tag score increased in both tags, or only in the first tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the answers to the following two questions, your tag score is based on the current tags of the question:

- [Tag-badges exploit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30193/tag-badges-exploit)
- [Can tag badges be gamed by editing the tags of a question which has an answer which was previously upvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83159/can-tag-badges-be-gamed-by-editing-the-tags-of-a-question-which-has-an-answer-wh)

Comment: Thanks you for the references. It seems that searching for `tag exploit` gives the right hits, but I didn't think of such a malicious term :-)