# Can I add more relevant tags to questions I've answered to get tag badges?

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag-badges exploit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30193/tag-badges-exploit)

After looking at some other users' profiles, I assume that badges can be earned for upvoted answers in *each* versioned tag, rather than somehow summing them all together.

If so, then, one the one hand, I suppose this provides more opportunity for earning badges; however, on the other hand, it can sometimes make it much harder to earn badges for tags with relatively low traffic and several versions.

I suppose if this was a real concern, a user could improve their scores by editing the tags on all the questions they'd answered so that all the *relevant* versioned tags were always included.

But could such selective editing be considered as gaming the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the edit is accurate and is not removing relevant information (say another tag that is as or more relevant) I see this as a benign thing. It makes the question better and easier to find when searching, so improves the site, so in that light - a bonus.