# Tag badge not granted in long time, more than a few weeks

Tags: support, tags, badges, tag-badges

I seem to be due a tag badge on [pointfree](/questions/tagged/pointfree) tag for a long time now, more than a few weeks I think, but I've yet to receive it. I'm the first one that made the cut there.

[image]

Yes, I did retagged many of the posts now in the tag, but not all of them were with my answers, and all of them were valid edits IMHO. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115600/172601) says it's OK and "improves the site" as long as "edit is accurate". Naturally it was easier for me to find such posts among *my* answers, but I did manage to find a few others and tagged them as well.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be considered for tag badges.

Only 66 questions are under that tag.

Comment: ah, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: for some reason the answer you quote from (of which my Q is now marked as duplicate) did not appear when I typed my question, and doesn't appear now on the "related" sidebar... thanks again.