# Increased reputation to create new tags

Tags: discussion, reputation, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the create-new-tag threshold be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51949/should-the-create-new-tag-threshold-be-increased)

It seems that the reputation needed to create new tags has been recently increased to 1500. Why was this done?

As a user who was able to create new tags and no longer can, I would like to know the reasoning.

Comment: Here is the most recent discussion that sparked the change: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51949/should-the-create-new-tag-threshold-be-increased