# Are there any general rules for when a new tag should be created?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation

I see a number of tags at SO that seem useless. Before raising them for possible deletion, I'd like to know, are there any rules that are followed when creating a new flag?

The FAQ page doesn't say anything about tags, and the [tag privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) just says:

> **What is creating tags?**
>
> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. When you choose to create a new tag, you're asking a question in a topic that nobody before you (on this site, at least) ever has.
>
> **When should I create new tags?**
>
> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

Which isn't very explicit. It's obvious to me that there should be a [c](/questions/tagged/c) tag, because c is a computing language and if the question is in c you want to group it as such. But what about tags like [dna-sequence](/questions/tagged/dna-sequence). This is on here because the content of the programming problem happens to be about dna sequences. I think these types of tags need to be deleted, because we're not categorizing by content of a programming problem.

Instinctually if I'm parsing a DNA sequence (stored in a string) I would tag with [string](/questions/tagged/string) and whatever language, not what's stored in the string. Am I thinking about this correctly? Is there any FAQ or post anywhere that actually supports my desire to eliminate such tags?

Answer (score 1):

There sure are, try reading the links from the [tag-creation tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-creation/info):

> - [How do I correctly tag my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878)
> - [Creating new tags is a "Bad Thing"™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53469)

If you're ever unsure, just start a discussion on Meta about whether the tag should be created. It can be a bit confusing on Stack Overflow since not all these rules existed when tagging first started, and there's a lot of not-so-great tags floating around.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, yet disagree. Tags serve 2 purposes:

- Identify what category a question falls into
- Expand on the title, helping potential answerers know if they would be any help or not.

In the example you gave using a DNA-sequence, tagging it [dna-sequence](/questions/tagged/dna-sequence) would be appropriate, as you would often treat it differently than a string that said "Orange Pancakes". Tagging it [dna-sequence](/questions/tagged/dna-sequence) **as well as** [string](/questions/tagged/string) would be the most beneficial to the question asker, and would help someone glancing at a question identify what the question is over.

Generally, I would create new tags (as I work with areas that SO is lacking in) if it:

- can describe the question "This question is a question about *insert tag name*, and can be summerized as such.
- Programming language is not found, nor any synonyms are available (happened to me several times)
- Covers a new topic, that SO has not tagged yet (say, P2P data using flashes and cameras between phones)

I would **NOT** make a new tag if it:

- is a typo
- is a fairly common problem in another tag area, using the same language
- uses 2 or 3 different tags would help just the same
- condenses 2 or more tags into one

Comment: Interesting, your opinion `•Expand on the title` is actually an exact opposite as to [one of the links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions) animuson posted. Where they state `Don't try to summarize your question using the tags`

Comment: I am not saying you should summarize your question using tags, but they can be a valuable tool to help clarify your title if (like I do) you have trouble writing 'good' titles that perfectly describe your question(s)