# Low-rep catch-22: Can't create new tags, must have a tag, can't spontaneously divine any existing tags that would be appropriate to the question

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions, new-users

Workin' on a new stackexchange site (gamedev), and my rep is starting level (thus low).  I was trying to post [my question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/mastermind-type-versus-system), but turns out I can't create any tags that I find appropriate to the question (after I submitted once, and answered a no-spam captcha once or twice). Then it turns out that I can't post a question with no tags (second submit, and another captcha).  so then I had to open up a new tab to read through the possible tags for the site, pick a really vague one just to fulfill the requirement, and submit again (third submit, third captcha).  So finally after 3 submissions and 3 captchas, I've gotten my question through the tag-specific-requirements hoops.

This was an annoying procedure for me, so for a newbie I'm sure it would be disruptive.

Comment: After taking a quick look over there, "balance" is an existing tag that works well with that question: you're trying to find a value for X (or multiple values) that keeps the game *balanced*. "difficulty", another existing tag, is probably a bit of a stretch, but could possibly work.

Comment: And as a follow-up, how are *any* new tags created on a new SE site? If on registration the maximum rep one can *start* with is 101, then how are tags developed?

Comment: @warren: I believe anyone can create tags in private beta.

Comment: @Michael Madsen I consider myself somewhat of a power user, and I have lots of experience with Stackoverflow, superuser, etc etc.  So this is me putting myself in the shoes of a new user.  For me, it's annoying (primarily because of the multiple captchas).  For a new user, I expect it would be a "time to leave this site" obstacle.

Comment: I propose that if a user has more than a certain number of rep on other Stack Exchange sites, then they can skip the low rep restrictions...

Comment: I linked accounts, so I have 130 rep on the site.  It's just that that rep doesn't solve the tag restrictions for me.

Comment: @Tchalvak: It was mainly intended as a suggestion to how you could improve the tags on that question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps one part of the solution would be to be more clear on tags that won't work (e.g. highlighting them red & italic) because those tags don't exist and you also don't have enough rep to create them.

Edit:  To clarify, the part of the problem this solves is:  **The site allows me to write tags that are new, without warning me in any way that said tags will prevent my question submission from succeeding.**

Comment: For new sites (and even SO in general) this would be a neat feature. I would like to see a huge warning label though to prevent useless tags. The only disadvantage is that it does require moderation to "approve" a tag

Comment: How about using a crossed-out font?

Comment: Adding to this idea, if these proposed crossed-out tags were visible to higher rep users, they could be edited into existence by someone else.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's backwards, there should be a relationship between how many tags there are on the system to the rep required to create.

IE, only 10 tags in the system have a low rep requirement

As it increases, increase rep requirement.

IE, 350 tags in system required 1.5k rep to create

Comment: [Going by users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51949/54262) seems to be more useful; and SO seems to need an increase about once a year.

Comment: While that is a cool scaling, that's probably not going to solve the usability problem?  The problem isn't a lack of tags on game-dev, I think.  As a newbie, I shouldn't be able to create my own tags (so what if I think my question is about fish?).  But that shouldn't be as much of an obstacle to a successful posting of a question as it currently is.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the rep threshold for creating tags is too high for new sites.

Comment: I don't know, 150 is kinda low (on SO it takes 2000). I like (Tchalvak's other solution)[http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65203/low-rep-catch-22-cant-create-new-tags-must-have-a-tag-cant-spontaneously-div/65204#65204] better.

Comment: It does **not** take 2k rep. on SO to create new tags.

Comment: It is currently 1.5k rep on SO to create new tags, [increased](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51949/54262) from 250 a few months ago.

Comment: Basically new sites should (and do) start with lower thresholds. Maybe the starting threshold is still too high.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a section at the end of your post asking a high-rep user to create the tag and retag your post.

Comment: That doesn't help, because there's a requirement of at least one tag.  So the catch-22 would still be an obstacle before a new user could even ask for help.

Comment: @Tchalvak, maybe on *new* sites we need a tab "please-retag" to cover that case

Comment: @Tchalvak: Place it in the C# tag.  But then, do move the note asking for a retag to the top :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another part of the whole solution would be to try to make appropriate suggestions for starting tags for low rep users in the tag field.

**Edit:** To clarify, I meant (for low rep users) **continue** to show popular tags as suggestions beyond just alphabetic matches, so that they don't have to fish alphabetically in the dark.

Or alternatively could just **always** display some top tags in text -next- to the tag field so that resource doesn't go away the moment you start typing in the field (for unable-to-create-new-tags users only?).

Comment: indeed this already happens; note that the tag field is pre-populated with a selection from the top (n) tags as a hint

Answer (score -1):

If I were a newbie, I would just want the problem to go away.  So perhaps if I submit my question without the "you must have at least one tag" requirement met, a generic, default tag of some kind should just be tacked on, instead of forcing the new user to jump through hoops?