# Feature request: Ability to add a new tag pending review for users without the privilege

Tags: feature-request

So there are occasions where a new user wants to add a tag but lacks the rep. Two examples of this happening to me:

- I want to add a cornmeal tag to the cooking site.
- I want to add an XSD tag to the webapps site.

Now I could request via meta (which I guess I did) or even flag my own post for moderator attention, but I miss out on the taxonomist badge then. Finally, I feel that there are a lot of cases when new users would be generating good new tags. For example, I would expect that if a snobol programmer were to discover stackexchange, he would start asking snobol questions on SO, and mainframe questions on SF.

I do realize that adding new tags did not always require such high rep as I have earned the taxonomist badge on super user.

Comment: It is not "If", there is a Cobol tag already.  :-)

Comment: I apologize Bo for picking on the cobol programmers, and not doing my research. BTW my first "real job" was as a third shift AS/400 operator in December 2002, so I of all people should have known better.

Answer (score 1):

This is debatable, because as you touched on, the create tags privilege used to be much lower -- it was [increased](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51949/should-the-create-new-tag-threshold-be-increased) because so many low-rep users were creating terrible tags. You have to factor in that making high-rep users review something isn't "free" -- it takes time for that to happen. If a large percentage of new tags created by low-rep users are going to be rejected, then it might not be worth the time sink reviewing them all just to occasionally get good ones. I'm not saying that will necessarily be the case, but we've not had good experiences in the past with tags created by new users

Comment: I agree there is an increased cost for the moderator, but that could be mitigated by increasing the cost to the end user. You could display a modal dialog informing the user that their new tag requires review to make them more cognizant of the fact. You could also set the rep bar for proposing new tags to 150 or 200 rep. That would require even a "proven" user from another SE site to be somewhat active on that site.

Comment: @Justin That's a nice thought, but the warning when you're [suggesting an edit](http://so.mrozekma.com/edit-suggestion-warning.png) is about as eye-catching as you can get and people still miss it -- a modal dialog might slow them down, but I doubt it. 150 is exactly what the old threshold was and it clearly didn't keep out all the terrible tags

Comment: I think there should be a warning even when 10k users create a new tag!