# New tag request jquery-isotope

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, tag-creation

I recently asked a [question about Isotope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233270/jquery-isotope-possible-chrome-bug), a new jQuery [plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) created by user [desandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182183/desandro).

I thought it would be appropriate to create the [jquery-isotope](/questions/tagged/jquery-isotope) tag since there are also [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isotope) it would apply to.

Since I [don't have enough rep to create the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51949/should-the-create-new-tag-threshold-be-increased) I'm requesting it be added here.

Answer (score 5):

I edited your question and added the [jquery-isotope](/questions/tagged/jquery-isotope) tag...