# When are topic badges awarded?

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

Hopefully I can ask this question before it becomes "no longer relevant"...

I was looking forward to passing [400 upvotes in the 'git' tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=git&sort=stats&pagesize=15), which I seem to have recently, but haven't been awarded the badge just yet.

My question is, when are these topic badges awarded? Is that more of a daily periodic job or some background task? I ask because I'm curious since they don't seem to work like the regular badges (awarded on next login), not because I'm being whingy and I want my shiny new badge *now*.

(Us high-rep users need *something* to look forward to!)

Comment: IIRC, it's only checked daily.  Not sure though, so this is just a comment.

Comment: Same as Joel Coehoorn. The only source I have is an unverified rumor.

Comment: I think this is the first tag-badge I haven't been surprised with, so perhaps I can try to confirm when it happens.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-do-badges-get-awarded-by-a-service-or-on-each-change. Not sure which answer is the correct one though.

Answer (score 3):

From my previous experiences, my tag badges (on Meta) were awarded around server rollover time (right now around 8PM Eastern).

Comment: That would be 0000 UTC, right? (I'm trying to remember when DST ends in EDT...)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's correct, Greg. Daylight savings time typically ends sometime in October..right around Halloween?

Comment: According to the tooltips, right now it is about 19:30 UTC. So check back in about four and a half hours.

Comment: Between 8PM and 9PM Eastern sounds right. I can't recall exactly, but I'm pretty sure I got awarded my MATLAB badge on SO in that window.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I was awarded the tag badge at approximately 05:00 UTC. I don't know whether this conclusively answers the question or not, because it seems like an unusual time for the badge processing to be run.

Comment: It *could* at a guess relate to the system usage profile... when can we run a potentially expensive query?