# Badges algorithm details

Tags: discussion, badges, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated)

How do badges work, in terms of implementation and database structure? For example, how are the badges implemented in the database, and how does the algorithm know which badge to choose from when there can be a duplication of steps in order to get one of badges?

Answer (score 3):

Elves. It's all done by elves. The DB just records which badges the elves have conferred on which users.

Comment: Are the elves riding on unicorns and eating waffles? That would be awesome!

Answer (score 3):

[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]
Then we have some queries to figure out who should get what.  It's similar to the [multi-use combinatorics problem](http://Im.joking.read.Johns.answer)

Comment: I can only upvote this after you have proven this is real. Give me a gold badge, and I believe you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! +1 from me now -- although populist would have been enough :)

Comment: When would it be necessary to manually award someone a badge? Under what circumstances would the daily queries miss something?

Comment: @Ether: You might want to follow Tom's link about the multi-use combinatorics problem.

Comment: I don't believe this is true. As if there'd be a 'Be Careful!' warning.

Comment: @balpha: links, schminks.

Answer (score 2):

Each badge is going to have it's own set process.

For example, the "Tumbleweed" badge doesn't need to run a schedule more often than once daily.

But the "Good Answer" badge could easily be event-driven.

The real answer is: it depends.