# Does the [algorithm] tag serve a purpose?

Tags: discussion, tags

Does the [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) tag serve any purpose? I mean, the one here on Meta, not Stack Overflow.

- It smells like a meta tag
- It only has 17 questions
- It's use is not clearly visible from the asked questions

Should it be removed?

Comment: Fixed the tag link for you

Comment: Hey cool, didn't know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes it serves to document and tag the various algorithms that are behind several of StackExchange's features. Some examples of proper usage:

1. [Frontpage content algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86071/frontpage-content-algorithm)
2. [Badges algorithm details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38605/badges-algorithm-for-so)
3. [What algorithm does Stack Exchange use to determine if a question may be subjective?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/what-algorithm-does-stackoverflow-use-to-determine-if-a-question-may-be-subjectiv)
4. [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)

Unfortunately, there are other shitty questions mixed in with the rest and those should be torched.

Comment: Should we set the tag wiki to reflect that and provide some guidance for the future?

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't be a bad idea.