# Missing badges - how long could this take?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated)

I received one `Notable question` badge for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169051/code-golf-word-frequency-chart) (3 days ago) iirc but with a view count of 7731 I would have expected several more to [show up by now](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81179/christophed) (at least Popular Question, Good Question etc...).

I've read that badges can take several days to show up but I was wondering if anyone can provide any insight as to how long this process can take (I'm a bit afraid they won't show up: I've seemingly always had badges pop up quite fast in the past).

Comment: CW shouldn't matter for these badges, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your profile you have one question with >2500 views and one Notable Question badge. You also have two questions with score >= 25 and two Good Question badges. This all sounds correct to me, or am I misunderstanding something about your question?

Comment: As far as I knew those badges can get awarded multiple times (or maybe they can only get appointed once *per question*?

Comment: Hmm, looking @ my stats that could probably be it. I thought I'd get 7 `popular question` badges for a viewcount of 7000+ (but that may have been a little too optimistic ;-)

Comment: If this is the case (can someone confirm?), maybe it should be added to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work-in-stackoverflow that badges that can get awarded multiple times only can get awarded once per question.

Comment: @ChristopheD: It's still just one Popular Question and gets only one such badge, even if it is very popular :). But for questions that exceed the criteria of the bronze badges there are the silver/gold badges of the same type, so you can still get something from it.

Comment: well if you state it that way it sounds obvious ;-) Thanks for the answer (I'll mark as accepted)

Answer (score 1):

A few days is too long; as far as I know the least-frequent batch jobs on the Stack Exchange sites run nightly.

Is it possible that you earned this badge previously for a question that has since been deleted? In that case you would have a surplus of one badge, which would be consumed when you next become eligible for one of the same type.

Personally I would prefer that a reputation recalc did a "badge recalc" as well, but hey, I didn't write the code :D

Comment: Hmm. I've not had any question deleted so that could not have been the culprit. A badge recalc would be a nice feature indeed ;-)