# When are the new badge verifications performed?

Tags: support, badges

Some badges are not awarded after the event has happened.

They require analysis, some of them are Suffrage, Tenacious, Unsung Hero, Quorum...

These calculations are triggered by some schedules.

What are theses badges?
When are those calculated?

Comment: I always assumed that there was a schedule that runs say every hour that performs these tasks and awards to them to the user.  Once awarded then a flag to notify the user is set? Why would you need to know anyway?

Comment: I just noticed this, and wanted to know when it was happening and for what badges, I checked Stack Exchange and verified that I should get an Tenacious Badge, however I haven't received and I'm wondering if this will be checked I don't know once every 3 months.

Comment: Hate to say it, but you don't qualify for the Tenacious badge. You need *more* than five zero-score accepted answers to get it, but you have *exactly* five such answers.

Comment: Thanks @RegDwight but I still want to know when are these calculated.

Answer (score 5):

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298953/295232):

> Most badges (with the exception of the [Informed badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164073)) are awarded by a scheduled job which runs once every hour and are [non-deterministic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125108/295232), i.e. there is no *guarantee* that your badge will be awarded within an hour.

More details can be found in [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/295232)

I did some analysis in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com), plotting the number of awarded badges versus the UTC time. Some badges seem to be (mostly) awarded by a job that runs once a day, for example [**Archaeologist**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist):

[image]
<sub>([source](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1139790/what-time-of-day-are-badges-awarded?badgeName=Archaeologist&fromDate=2018-01-01#graph))</sub>

Others are awarded quite soon after the user or post becomes eligible, e.g. [**Great Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer); note that it follows the general activity pattern on Stack Overflow where US and European office hours are the most busy:

[image]
<sub>([source](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1139790/what-time-of-day-are-badges-awarded?badgeName=Great+Answer&fromDate=2018-01-01#graph))</sub>

[**Tenacious**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious) seems to fall somewhat in between:

[image]
<sub>([source](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1139790/what-time-of-day-are-badges-awarded?badgeName=Tenacious&fromDate=2018-01-01#graph))</sub>

Comment: In regards to the Tenacious badge, I could imagine that the percentage is recalculated on a daily interval, whilst the exact threshold of 5 is evaluated more frequent, resulting in the shown behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

If someone can get their hands on an old Stack Exchange 1.0 data dump there is a `Badges.xml` file or similar that contains this information.

I used to have it but now I can't find it anymore. =(

Comment: I think Math Overflow still regularly release data dumps

Comment: The http://data.stackexchange.com/ is not appropriate?