# Bug with Suffrage and Vox Populi badges?

Tags: support, badges, voting

I was awarded the Suffrage and Vox Populi badges today respectively at 29 votes and 39 votes according to my account statistics, but the badges state that they are awarded for 30 votes and 40 votes respectively. This is a bug, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Conversely, I'm pretty sure I was awarded Vox Populi recently, but now it doesn't show up in my list of badges.

Comment: Probably this link will help - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72240/when-are-the-new-badge-verifications-performed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Was one of the answers you cast a vote on deleted? Maybe it was an incorrect answer you downvoted, which the answerer later deleted. I'm not sure if votes on deleted answers count toward the daily limit, but if you can't cast any more votes past your 39th, I guess that would be it.

Comment: yep that's more likely the case here..

Comment: Now, that you mention it, I'm 99% sure that's exactly what happened. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Right now, your profile is showing that you used all 40 votes.

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-1274121213.png

Maybe you were viewing a cached version when you saw 39.

Comment: It's showing it now, but when I received the Vox Populi badge, I voted once more to make the number 40.