# OP namebox slightly overlaps text on the above line in comments

Tags: bug, comments, display-names, original-poster

Perhaps that's toooooo minor, but being QA I can't leave it unsubmitted: looking for the details of `Vox Populi` badge, I noticed in comments for that answer (actually, only one at the time of posting this): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95959/208917 that **OP namebox slightly overlaps "long" letters** on the above line:

[image: Overlap]

It's reproduced for **IE8**, latest stable **Chrome** and **FF** for **WinXP**, but for **Win7** there's a difference: somehow **latest FF** renders the content correctly:

[image: FF19 renders OK]

It's also NOT observed for **Chrome** on **Mac** (as noted in comments):

[image: Chrome on Mac is OK]

I'm not 100% sure this is common for all sites - I simply can't find the relevant sample on main SO, but it seems that it's only a matter of time to locate appropriate comment.

QA at your service.

Comment: [No problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G09oj.png) in Chrome on my Mac (which uses Arial to render it).

Comment: @Arjan thanks for the update, will include that in post - I have no Mac to check, perhaps this is Win-specific.

Comment: Can you check [what font is actually used](http://superuser.com/questions/43280/utility-to-determine-the-font-used-on-a-site/43482#43482)?

Comment: @Arjan **Firebug Lite** shows this for Chrome: `font-family Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif`.

Comment: @Arjan It's **Arial** 12.5 size - the first one from CSS list.

Comment: (As an aside: Chrome does not *need* Firebug lite; it has [built-in Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).)

Comment: @Arjan thanks for the suggestion, I marked your comment useful - but I simply more familiar with Firebug since FF is my default browser since v 2.X)

Comment: (Of course, Firefox [doesn't need Firebug either](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GT4ql.png) `;-)`)

Comment: @TimStone agree, feel free to close as dupe. Sorry I didn't found that! However, I'm curious it still unfixed for so long...