# New 'Informed' badge does not show in badge total

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Yesterday I just got the `Informed` badge for reading the new about page, I was awarded the badge, but my badge count on the top still shows 28 bronze badges even though I now have 29 after being awarded the badge.

[image]

Comment: I just tried that and it happened to me as well.

Comment: Hmm. It may be either delayed or site specific, as the one I got on askdifferent is registering, but my SO one (which I got later) is not.

Comment: @Jaydles I got it last night, so unless there is a very long delay it might just be an SO issue.

Comment: A fix will go live shortly.

Comment: @Emmett status-completed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is fixed now. The Informed badge, being the first badge that is awarded *immediately*, uses a slightly different code path, and so this bug came along with it.

Comment: Nice! Is this new badge announced anywhere? (here on Meta or blog)

Comment: We'll likely announce the new about page in blog post soon. The badge may get a mention.

Comment: @Emmett you should mention it in the new about page!  Oh wait...   Also thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: The problem is still persisting; no Informed tag is being awarded to users even after going through about page! help!!