# How is the badge awarding system implemented?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do badges get awarded? By a service or on change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-do-badges-get-awarded-by-a-service-or-on-change)

I was surprised by the system that awards badges whenever a certain task is completed. How is that implemented? Does it use triggers in the database? Is it done purely in code? If it is code, what is the design?

I realize that maybe no-one knows the exact answer, but how do you think it's implemented?

Comment: BD = BetaDase??

Comment: Sorry I am Spanish (Base de Datos) LOL

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-do-badges-get-awarded-by-a-service-or-on-change

Answer (score 2):

From what I've understood, at least some are implemented as timed jobs that periodically check if a new badge should be awarded. I assume these run on different intervals depending on the badge.

I don't know if some of the more trivial badges are awarded based on a trigger, or if the job just runs really frequently for those. They appear to be awarded quite quickly.

Comment: But don't you think thats a huge use of resources, i mean, if for each badge you have to check a great amount of users...

Comment: @eversor: For those that can be hooked to triggers, not really, especially if indices are set up intelligently. Some of the others are only scanned for occasionally (once a day?) so they could be quite expensive I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Only the developers can answer this 100% which I doubt they will, as programmers prefer to keep the code/logic behind hidden.

From what I've seen, all the "first time you *[action here]*" badges are awarded instantly - no timed job in this case. So this means code running in every relevant place checking if it's your first *[something here]* it will add a badge.

More complex badges like [Revival](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/126/revival) (Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more) already requires checking more conditions, so most lilkely it's done by some timed job probably every few hours.

Comment: "I doubt they will, as programmers prefer to keep the code/logic behind hidden" -- I think SO is a bit different; multiple times I've seen devs post actual code snippets when explaining how something works/what was wrong

Comment: @MichaelMrozek true, hope this will be the case on this matter too. :)