# Why similar badges are clubbed together in recent badges?

Tags: support, badges

I am not able to understand why the similar badges are clubbed together. Here is a screen shot

[image: Recent Badges]

It is a bit odd that 4-5 people get `Necromancer` then will come people with Notable Questions. And almost all the yearling people log in at the same time. Though it may be logically possible. But is this actually the case?

Comment: Related: [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Badges are awarded in batches, and the batch process works per class of badges.

Thus, a set of Necromancer badges are awarded, then a batch of Good Answer badges are awarded, etc. Because this covers a certain time period for each badge, there are easily multiple people that have earned that badge, especially on Stack Overflow, and certainly for the easier badges.