# Excavator Badge is not awarded to me

Tags: support, badges

I have joined http://electronics.stackexchange.com about 4 days ago. After joining the next day I edited [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/15875/20279). As you can see it was being approved and I got 2 reputation points as normal rule applies. Now this post was about a year and 6 months old so I should be awarded the badge [image] `Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months`. I thought it might take time to award such badge, but as you can see it's been 3 days passed but still I haven't got this badge, is it a bug or misunderstanding of mine?

I have already read this question, titled [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/214722)

Answer (score 7):

As you already know the description of the [Excavator badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/158/excavator):

> Edited first post that was **inactive** for 6 months.

The post you have edited is more than 6 months old but not **inactive** for 6 months or more. It was [edited 2 days ago](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/15875/3) before your edit.

Comment: Ah, so that's why i saw that question. It was confusion for me, that how come i got that old question to edit ? So it is like i joined the site and at the same time this question comes at top because of the editing, and i edited it again. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Raynold - Hmm probably you visited either [homepage](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or the [active tab](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) which show us recently modified posts.

Comment: yeah i visited the home page.