# Why haven't I been awarded the Electorate badge?

Tags: support, badges, electorate-badge

So, I here's my [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073001/steve-p).  I voted on 601 questions and 646 answers.  Why don't I have the *Electorate Badge*?

Comment: How long ago was the 601th vote cast? The script which awards badges only runs periodically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Badge grants are not immediate, you should see it when the job runs shortly.

Answer (score 10):

But... you *do* have the badge.

I knew if I waited long enough I'd be right.

In any case, badges aren't always (ever?) awarded instantly. Sorry you had to wait so long.

See also [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated)

Comment: A 5 minute wait?! This is outrageous... I want my money back.

Comment: @hayd - okay, here is your $0 back