# How do I unlock the Autobiographer badge?

Tags: bug, badges

I've filled out all the profile fields, but I still don't have the badge. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: How long ago did you complete it? The badges are not always awarded immediately, but upon a scheduled task

Comment: I see it already in your profile

Comment: I had everything filled in except the About Me. I didn't think that field would count. I filled out the About Me earlier this morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it already in your profile.

Badges & reputation are sometimes delayed. Most badges are awarded by a scheduled task/process which by design runs only every fixed interval of time.

Comment: Not accurate. Most badges are awarded by a scheduled task/process which by design runs only every fixed interval of time. [Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1721/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, thank you for your correction. Just added your comment into my answer.