# Change Informed badge text on about page when not logged in

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, tour, informed-badge

This is probably splitting hairs. When you reach the bottom of the about pages on the main sites, you earn the Informed badge. But if you're not logged in, the text on the page still says you earned the Informed badge. Then if you do proceed to login or create an account on the site, the badge isn't awarded until you scroll to the bottom of the about page again.

It seems like either the badge text should be hidden, or add a hint about logging into the site to earn the badge. Or maybe if the user does login/create an account after reading the page award the badge. I know badges are awarded from [a scheduled service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated) so the latter suggestion could be a challenge to implement as it stands today. I also can see the argument that having a user visit the about page multiple times is an unintended feature.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you aren't logged in, the page states (my emphasis):

> In fact, you **can earn** a badge just for reading this page:
>
> Informed   Read the entire about page

This is factually correct. I don't see any reason to change it.

[It was already the case when you posted this feature request.](http://web.archive.org/web/20130827174758/https://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice that text changed... good catch.