# Shouldn't I be getting an "Enlightened" badge for my answer?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, accepted-answer

I know this has been asked before but can someone explain to me what specific criteria I failed to meet for being awarded the **Enlightened** Badge?

> *Enlightened*
>
> - silver; awarded multiple times
> - Be the first person to answer a question, and receive a score of at least ten for that answer. The answer must be accepted by the question owner, and it mustn't be a self-accept.

1. Be the first person to answer - *check*
2. Score >=10 - *check*
3. Answer accepted by question owner - *check*

[image]

The answer was accepted at 29-02-2016 01:03:55 UTC time. It's been more than 24 hours now.

[image]

I got the "Good Answer" badge (answer score of 25 or more) but not the Enlightened badge for [this answer on EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/310384/150645).

[image]

This related [Meta SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1721/311151) suggests that a job takes care of awarding badges. If it's not done within 24 hours, the answer didn't meet the criteria.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were not the first to answer this question, though not by much. Your answer is timed at 08:35:29, but there is a rival answer by ringo timed at 08:35:22

The [question's timeline](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/310381/timeline) shows this pretty clearly. If you hover over the first column in the report the times will appear as tooltips, alternatively click on toggle format at the bottom of the report and you'll see all the dates directly.

Note that if you sort answers by oldest first, the accepted answer is still shown at the top so be careful if you're using that to check whether you were the first to answer.

Comment: Thanks but I am confused. Why does my answer show up first and not ringo's when I sort by oldest answer first? 

On a related note, how do I see timeline for the posts?

Comment: added first point to answer, for timelines see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view