# Some meta sites insist that I take the main sites' tours, but don't recognize that I already have

Tags: bug, badges, per-site-meta, tour

On three sites:

- [User Ray Butterworth - Music Fans Meta Stack Exchange](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9209/ray-butterworth)
- [User Ray Butterworth - Operations Research Meta Stack Exchange](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3482/ray-butterworth)
- [User Ray Butterworth - Physics Meta Stack Exchange](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/269999/ray-butterworth)

my badges section shows no badges and instead tells me to "Take the Tour and earn your first badge".

But even if I take the tour several times, that message doesn't change.

Strangely, those are all "meta" sites, and the tours are for the main sites.
Even stranger, I took the tours for the main sites long ago (e.g. Physics on July 29).

[image: Physics Meta showing the "tour" message]

#### Update:

Unix.Meta.SE was another site where I had this same problem.

I just read some of the items there and upvoted one (not gratuitously), and a few minutes later I was awarded the `Supporter` badge, and now the "tour" problem has gone away.

Strangely though, I was at the same time awarded the `Yearling` and `Autobiographer` as well.

So this bug isn't simply a matter of annoyance, it's actually blocking the awarding of other badges.

Comment: @Ollie, I guess that's because it would show that information only if I am the one looking at it. I just added a screenshot of my Physics meta page.

Comment: @Glorfindel _*facepalm\*_.  I knew I'd seen that post before, *and* that you can't earn that badge there.  Sorry, Ray.

Comment: @Ollie no problem. You yet have to experience a situation where you write an answer to a question, and then it gets rightfully closed as a duplicate of a question *you already answered two years before*. Those are my facepalms :)

Comment: @Glorfindel I hope your nose doesn't hurt ;)

Comment: @Ollie, I'd accept this as a duplicate, but I just discovered an additional side effect of the bug, not documented in the other item, that makes it more than an annoyance. See my "Update:".

Comment: @Ray I think that "*it's actually blocking the awarding of other badges*" is likely a premature assumption- It's probable that the badges getting awarded at once was simply the badge script stepping in and awarding all the badges you were eligible for, [just like normal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated).