# Why is the awarding of Nice Answer badge much faster than Enlightened badge?

Tags: discussion, bug, badges, enlightened-badge, nice-answer

I have this answer I did yesterday on SO:

> [Convert type str (with number and words) column into int pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536454/convert-type-str-with-number-and-words-column-into-int-pandas/65536479#65536479)

And I got my tenth upvote today. So I got the Nice Answer badge an hour ago:

> https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=8708364

But I was a bit confused that why I didn't get the Enlightened badge. As in the badge page, the trigger for the badge is:

> First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more

I did that in that answer.

But now just 5 minutes ago I was awarded the Enlightened badge.

> https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened?userid=8708364

But that is a big time difference between the time of awarding for the two badges.

Why is it like that? Why is there a such a big time gap?

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't think so, that is for all badges, and doesn't specify the two badges (Enlightened and Nice Answer), also their in the same category of badges, why are the times of delivering so off, that's my question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated):

> These badges are awarded by scheduled jobs; there are a number of scheduled tasks at different intervals (every few (e.g. 5) minutes; hourly; daily etc) that do a range of things

Depends on the complexity of checking for the badge existence, there will be different job for it.

The "Nice Answer" badge is very "easy" to check: it's just checking the plain score. So the check can run pretty often without overloading the system.

However, the Enlightened badge has more complex criteria. The job awarding it need to check more factors, e.g. if the answer is first. This is costly, in terms of resources, as it involves more SQL or code behind the scenes. Hence, the job runs less often, e.g. every two hours.

Comment: Oh I understand now...