# Nice Answer and Enlightened badges not awarded

Tags: discussion, badges, accepted-answer

Yesterday, [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2437516/446262) got its tenth upvote and it has no downvotes. Furthermore, it is the only answer to its question, and it got accepted. Therefore, I should have earned both a Nice Answer badge and an Enlightened badge, but that did no happen. Any idea about the reason?

Comment: Last vote seems to be less than 24h ago. Wait a bit more.

Comment: There's a percentage chance of a particular badge to be checked for whenever the routine badge scripts run. Sometimes one can get unlucky in running. See [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated)

Comment: That would make more sense if [the badge itself had no recent awards](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer), but it's been awarded as recently as 34 minutes ago. It's not possible for a user to be skipped over if the check ran.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already received those badges for this answer back in November of 2017 when the answer first reached a score of 10.

One of the upvotes was subsequently removed in 2019, moving it back down to a score of 9, but we don't revoke badges when you become ineligible.